# sqlite, UPDATE OR REPLACE

Tags: sqlite

I do something like

UPDATE OR REPLACE someTable SET a=1, b=2 WHERE c=3

I expect if it doesnt exist it will be inserted into the DBs. But nothing happens and i get no errors. How can i insert data, replace it if it already exist and use a where for the condition (instead of replacing BC of a unique ID)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Careful, INSERT OR REPLACE doesn't have the expected behaviour of an "UPDATE OR REPLACE".

If you don't set the values for all fieds, INSERT OR REPLACE is going to replace them with default values, whereas with an UPDATE you expect to keep the old values.

See my answer here for an example: [SQLite - UPSERT *not* INSERT or REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace/4253806#4253806)

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO [someTable] (a,b) VALUES(1,2) WHERE c = '3'
```

Comment: This syntax is not valid.

Consider https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html for insert, and
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html for select.


No where clause can be added after values(...).