# How do I update if exists, insert if not (AKA "upsert" or "merge") in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, insert-update, upsert

Is there an easy way to `INSERT` a row when it does not exist, or to `UPDATE` if it exists, using one MySQL query?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).  For example:

```
INSERT INTO `usage`
(`thing_id`, `times_used`, `first_time_used`)
VALUES
(4815162342, 1, NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`times_used` = `times_used` + 1
```

Comment: Wow, that's awesome.  Do other RDMSs have this feature?

Comment: Yeah, I believe SQL Server's equivalent is called `MERGE`.  In general, the concept is often referred to as `"UPSERT"`.

Comment: But this doesn't work when there is no prim.key present. 
My table looks like this:
geb | topic | visited

I want to insert 
INSERT INTO table SET visited=NOW(), geb=1, topic=1
But if there is already a combination of geb=1 && topic=1 then it should update the row instead of insert a new one.

Comment: @blub: If you create a unique key on `geb` and `topic` it will work (`ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE geb_by_topic (geb, topic)`).

Comment: I didn't enter a prim.key because i then had to use a new column cause geb and topic are both not unique.
I didn't know it was possible to make a key pairing two columns!!
Thanx chaos.

Comment: @Brian: Oracle's equivalent is also called `MERGE` but I'm not sure if its syntax is identical to SQL Server's.

Comment: @iAn: That isn't really all it does. If you check for existence using a `SELECT`, then perform an `INSERT`, you have concurrency issues that don't exist if you're using an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: As must of the time `on duplicate` is hit, is this codes performance good? is there a better solution?

Comment: I take it of 'thing_id' is set to autoincrement (and is the primary key) and you pass it '0' the result will be an insert at the next value for 'thing_id' ?

Comment: @Brooks: If you pass it a 0, it will actually use 0 as the value.  So don't do that.  Don't pass it anything, or pass it a `NULL`, to allow the `auto_increment` behavior to work (which otherwise, yes, works as you presume; see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: How do you do this if there are multiple unique indexes? I only want to update a record if the record already existing has 2 properties that are equal, not one or the other.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` part of the mechanism means that it only goes to an `UPDATE` if the `INSERT` attempt generates a duplicate in a unique key. If that wouldn't occur in your case, then you can't use this mechanism to address it.

Comment: For those who are wondering, this example WILL update times_used for the discovered duplicate row.

Comment: I am already using this and I want to extend this question. Is there any way to get the effected(updated/inserted) ID form this method

Comment: @Ruwantha: The docs contain an example for doing this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @chaos: It is very helpful , How ever in my case id is not a increment  one. I guess there is no solution for that.

Comment: Thank you, and you can use `VALUES(col)` to get the value from the insert argument in case of duplicate. Eg: `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE b = VALUES(b), c = VALUES(c)`

Comment: @chaos and others, I want to use this query, but I want to check if there is a record against project_id = pId and expert_id = eId then UPDATE ml_match else INSERT project_id, expert_id, ml_match and ignore the other columns. Can you write query? Is ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE work only on primary key or any field name?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but the Google lead me here recently so I imagine others come here, too.

@chaos is correct: there is the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax.

However, the original question asked about MySQL specifically, and in MySQL there is the [`REPLACE INTO ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) syntax.  IMHO, this command is easier and more straightforward to use for upserts.  From the manual:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Note this is not standard SQL.  An example from the manual:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

mysql> REPLACE INTO test VALUES (1, 'Old', '2014-08-20 18:47:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> REPLACE INTO test VALUES (1, 'New', '2014-08-20 18:47:42');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | data | ts                  |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 | New  | 2014-08-20 18:47:42 |
+----+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Edit:** Just a fair warning that `REPLACE INTO` isn't like `UPDATE`.  As the manual says, `REPLACE` deletes the row if it exists, then inserts a new one.  (Note the funny "2 rows affected" in the example above.)  That is, it will replace the values of *all* columns of an existing record (and not merely update *some* columns.)  The behavior of MySQL's `REPLACE INTO` is much like that of Sqlite's `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace) for some workarounds if you only want to update a few columns (and not all columns) if the record already exists.

Comment: Old question, I know: but for anyone thinking of doing this; please keep in mind using the `REPLACE INTO` has a potential "gotcha." If you've got any "ON DELETE CASCADE" magic going on, this `REPLACE` will cause the cascade to trigger - possibly causing huge issues. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723145/what-is-the-performance-difference-between-insert-ignore-and-replace-in-mysql#comment5217271_4723200