# checking if a record is already present in mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [insert contacts into database but does not want to duplicate already existing contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702059/insert-contacts-into-database-but-does-not-want-to-duplicate-already-existing-co)

what i intend to do is, check if a user's account  is already stored in my database, redirect to another url else store his data in the database. following is the query i wrote. it is not working please suggest where i went wrong. 
thaks.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM centraluser where id = '$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if($row) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE central SET time = '$time' WHERE id = '$id'");
    $url = "http://www.somesite.com";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Sorry! you can't register twice.");</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href = "'.$url.'";</script>';die;exit;

}
else  {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO centraluser VALUES ('$id','$name','$email','0','5000','0','0','$birthday','$time')");
    echo('welcome new user');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM centraluser WHERE id = '$id'");
$user_data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if(empty($user_data)) {
    $qry = "INSERT INTO centraluser VALUES    ('$id','$name','$email','0','5000','0','0','$birthday','$time')";
    mysql_query($qry);
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 'welcome new user';
    header("Location:dashboard.php"); // write your main page after login
    exit();
}
else {
     $qry="UPDATE central SET time = '$time' WHERE id = '$id'";
     mysql_query($qry);
     $url = "http://www.somesite.com";
     echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Sorry! you can\'t register twice.");</script>';
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href ="'.$url.'";</script>';
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are having the error with this code

escape string and use this code below.

and define what part of your code is still not working.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Sorry! you can\'t register twice.");</script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href = "'.$url.'";</script>';die;exit;
```

Comment: sorry to put it this way, but i am aware of it, was just a message not being used in the actual program. thanks anyway.