# Check if record already exists in database

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [insert contacts into database but does not want to duplicate already existing contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702059/insert-contacts-into-database-but-does-not-want-to-duplicate-already-existing-co)

Hello. I'm trying to check if an email already exists before I insert a duplicate.

So I need to check the database for the presence of the email address and if it exists ouput a message saying it already exists. Otherwise I want to insert the record into the database.

Here is the code I use to insert the email now, but I'm not sure how to check the database for existence.

```
$addEmailQuery  = sprintf("INSERT INTO `subscribe`(`Email`) VALUES('%s')",
                            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputEmail']));
        $addEmailResult = mysql_query($addEmailQuery);
        if($addEmailResult){
            echo 'Email successfully submitted';

        } else{
            echo 'Sorry, we could not submit your email. Please try again.';
        }
```

Anyone know how I would do this?

Comment: yes check if it already exists.  If so echo it already exists in db. else insert the email entered in form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDITED:**
The initial answer will pose problems in a multi-user environment.

You should do like

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702059/insert-contacts-into-database-but-does-not-want-to-duplicate-already-existing-co) to get it correct.

**ORIGINAL POST:**

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscribe WHERE Email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputEmail'])."'")))
{
     echo "already submitted";
}   
else
{

    $addEmailQuery  = sprintf("INSERT INTO `subscribe`(`Email`) VALUES('%s')",
                        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputEmail']));
    $addEmailResult = mysql_query($addEmailQuery);
    if($addEmailResult)
    {
       echo 'Email successfully submitted';

     } 
     else
     {
        echo 'Sorry, we could not submit your email. Please try again.';
     }

}
```

Comment: It will fail in a multi user environment - another user can insert between the select and your insert

Comment: @Mark: please suggest a solution then..

Comment: @mithunsatheesh for mysql see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

Comment: @Mark: thanks brother.. that helps.. also if you can, just edit this answer to make it correct.. may help others

Answer (score 0):

Do a SELECT before your Insert and check if a value is returned for this email.
Thats the simplest way to do it.

```
$CheckEmailQuery  = sprintf("SELECT `Email` FROM `subscribe` WHERE `Email` = '%s'",
                        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputEmail']));
    $CheckEmailResult = mysql_query($CheckEmailQuery);
    if($CheckEmailResult){
        // Do What you are doing above
    }
```

I have just given the idea but not tested it.