# On insert, how can I change the duplicate name to something else in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I am having a challenge working with multiple documents, particularly dealing with duplicate filenames in the database. I am trying to create a system in which an admin can add HTML documents. He will input two fields: name of the document and its source code.

When adding a document, the name (e.g. "A Page") and the filename (based on the name e.g. "a_page.html") will be inserted to the database and a file with the source code inside will be created on the server.

The problem now is what happens if I try to add another document with the same name e.g. "A Page". I would like the filename to be "a_page_2.html" to not overwrite the existing one. And if another with the same name, "a_page_3.html" and so on.

Is there a simple SQL statement for achieving?

Comment: In MySQL there's the ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax. You might want to look into that

Comment: Yes, you could set your fields as UNIQUE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702059/insert-contacts-into-database-but-does-not-want-to-duplicate-already-existing-co

Comment: Oh yes, I've looked at that. However, if there is a duplicate, I am trying to update the new record not the old record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no simple statement. There could be a_page_2.html already.

So, just make your document names already unique:

- insert new record in the database
- get unique id
- create the file using this id, by putting together given name and id

When selecting document name, you could do just

```
SELECT concat(name,'_',id) as name ...
```

It is similar to the way Stackoverflow creates question urls:

```
/questions/14919687/on-insert-how-can-i-change-the-duplicate-name-to-something-else-in-the-database/
            ^ id    ^ conventional name that can have 1000s duplicates
```

You can also get rid of conventional names at all, leaving ids only:
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919687/` still works

Comment: But then he'll get stuff like fileA_151235 instead of fileA_2

Comment: Hm... that is an interesting solution. Unfortunately for me, I am moving files from an old system to a new system having names already as "a_page.html", so I would need to rename them all. I would have to write a script to rename all files.

Answer (score -1):

- Make the file name column `UNIQUE`
- try to insert and if you got a duplicate key error, repeat with added number until successful

With PDO it could look like that:

```
class QueryException extends RuntimeException { }
class DuplicateKeyException extends QueryException { }

function executeInsert(PDOStatement $stmt) {
    try {
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        switch ($e->errorInfo[1]) {
            case 1062:
                throw new DuplicateKeyException($e->getMessage(), null, $e);
            default:
                throw new QueryException($e->getMessage(), null, $e);
        }
    }
}

$filename = 'a_page';
$contents = '<title>test</title>';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO documents (filename,contents) VALUES (:filename,:contents)');
$repeat = true; $counter = 0;
while ($repeat)
    try {
        $stmt->bindValue(
            ':filename',
            $filename . ($counter > 0 ? ("-$counter" : '') . '.html'
        );
        $stmt->bindValue(':contents', $contents);
        executeInsert($stmt);
        $repeat = false;
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException $e) {
        $repeat = true;
        $counter++;
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        $repeat = false;
        // error handling here
    }
}
```

Comment: I was actually thinking about something along those lines, but what happens if I have a filename that is called "a_page_10"? That means I would need to make 11 database calls and I don't think that would be too efficient. Chances are though I'll probably never get that many duplicates but anything can happen.

Comment: The alternative would be to make a `LIKE` query for the filename first to check for the smallest available number. If you expect that there are duplicates on almost every insert, you *might* consider that. But otherwise I would prefer a solution that is very fast >99% of the time and reasonable slower in special cases.