# If value exsists, update

Tags: mysql

Ok, I have a table where I will collect users devices. When a user logs in, I want it to register the device, if it already exists, it would just want to update the timestamp. This is only when a user logs in.

The table looks like this:

```
device_id => BIGINT AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
user_id => BIGINT FOREIGN KEY users(id)
device_name => VARCHAR(40) (Will be like 'Donald ducks iphone')
device_type => VARCHAR(10) (Will be defined by the client, like "IOS")
last_usage => TIMESTAMP (On update, new timestamp and all that)
```

So, when a user logs in, I have the user_id, device_name, device_type.

What I want:
if the id, name and type already exists in a row, just update timestamp, else insert the values.

Since this has nothing to do with the primary key I dont know how to do this. Of course I could do something like first select these values, return that and do the update/insert afterwards, but this does not feel right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make `device_name` and `device_type` unique.

Now you have a couple of options. You can use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO devices (...) VALUES(...)
```

or if you're worried important errors might get ignored, use:

```
INSERT INTO devices (...) VALUES(...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE device_id = device_id
```

Note that this is different from `REPLACE` in that this doesn't affect the old records at all, whereas `REPLACE` will create a new ID and timestamp.

EDIT: Since you now want to update the timestamp, use:

```
INSERT INTO devices (...) VALUES(...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_usage = NOW()
```

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` skips if the value already exists; it doesn't update it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4723200/924643

Comment: Sure, but since the device_id is AUTO_INCREMENT (and i dont know this id in insert/update) it creates it anyway... the Primary Key cant be the same since it's auto_increment. Should i set these columns that i have to some other key type or something?

Comment: @aam1r Yes I know, that is the behavior that is desired. `REPLACE` will change the ID and the timestamp, which is wrong.

Comment: @gubbfett See my edit. You should set a `UNIQUE` constraint for `device_name` and `device_type`.

Comment: BUT! It's not complete... Darn! I missed one thing... Since it does not update, the timestamp does not update... :(

Comment: @guubfett Yes, but you said you want for it to do nothing (which implies the timestamp should remain unchanged). You can update the timestamp if you like, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Yea sorry, that's right. I wrote the timestamp thing in the end, i changed the question in the beginning. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) in MySQL 5.0+:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted

Example:

```
REPLACE INTO TableName (user_id, device_id, device_name, device_type, last_usage) VAULES (1, 2, "Test Device Name, "Test Type", NOW());
```

Comment: This replaces the old record, changing the ID and timestamp, whereas the OP wants for it to `do nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each r In Me.Lstbox_Tables.ItemsSelected

'Create a recordset with required data

sql = "SELECT * FROM " & Me.Lstbox_Tables.ItemData(r)

'tablename = "Gahpp00d_" + rs!Table_Name

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbReadOnly)

Dim SheetName As String

SheetName = Replace(Me.Lstbox_Tables.ItemData(r), "GAHPP00D_", "")


On Error Resume Next

excelWbk.Sheets(SheetName).Select

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

MsgBox Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!!!"

MsgBox "Worksheet " & SheetName & " doesn't exist.", vbCritical, "Sheet Missing!!!"

excelWbk.Close False

appExcel.Quit


 Exit Sub

 End If
```

Comment: where does it say in the OP's question that they would like the answer in vb?? Also, what does this answer have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to convert this to mysql as its mssql but something along the lines of:

```
declare @count int
declare @user varchar
declare @machine varchar
declare @type as varchar

select @count = (select count(*) from [table] where user = @user and machine=@machine and type=@type)

if @count = 0
begin
insert into
[table]
select
@machine,
@user,
@type,
current_timestamp
end

if @count > 0
begin
update
[table]
set timestamp = current_timestamp
where
machine = @machine
and
user = @user
and
type = @type
end
```

Regards,

Marcus

Comment: One thing i will state about your setup is that if a number of users utilise the same device you will have multiple entries for that device. If this is being designed for Inventory purposes i would probably suggest updating the username too.