# REPLACE INTO with SELECT condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table:

```
mysql> desc dialog;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid1      | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| uid2      | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| mid       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| anonym_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and the same one:

```
mysql> desc dialogs;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid1      | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| uid2      | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| mid       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| anonym_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The 1-st one - dialog has a duplicate values which I don't need in the 2-nd - dialogs, the structure is the same, except unique index in dialogs table:

```
mysql> show index from dialogs;
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| dialogs |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dialogs |          0 | uid1_uid2 |            1 | uid1        | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dialogs |          0 | uid1_uid2 |            2 | uid2        | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dialogs |          1 | uid2      |            1 | uid2        | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dialogs |          1 | anonym_id |            1 | anonym_id   | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've found the way to insert into dialogs from dialog without duplicate key, but one:

```
REPLACE INTO dialogs SELECT * FROM dialog;
```

Works like a charm, but - I need either to test IF uid2>uid1 THEN switch them vice-versa and insert uid1=uid2 and uid2=uid1. Is there a solution to do almost the same, but with this clause with 1 query? 
I`d tried something like, but this query failed to execute:

```
REPLACE INTO dialogs 
    SELECT IF uid1<uid2 THEN * 
           ELSE id, uid2, uid1, mid, anonym_id 
END FROM dialog;
```

If so - please, post an example - I`ll try it.

Thx.

Comment: Is it ok with you that `REPLACE` is actually doing a deletion and then adding back, thereby incrementing the auto-increment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168928/what-are-practical-differences-between-replace-and-insert-on-duplicate-ke (Is that your _desired_ behavior?)

Comment: Please also post a small sample rowset for each table showing the input and desired output. If possible, please set it up at http://sqlfiddle.com. However, I think I understand what you're after so I'll post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `REPLACE INTO` which will increment your ids, you can [use `INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) to leave them in place if already present. As for switching the values of `uid1, uid2`, set the values in a `CASE`.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO dialogs (id, uid1, uid2, mid, anonym_id)
  SELECT
    id,
    /* First prefer uid1, then the opposite for uid2 */
    CASE WHEN uid1 < uid2 THEN uid1 ELSE uid2 END,
    CASE WHEN uid1 < uid2 THEN uid2 ELSE uid1 END,
    mid,
    anonym_id
  FROM dialog
```

[A little more on the difference between `REPLACE` and `INSERT IGNORE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723145/what-is-the-performance-difference-between-insert-ignore-and-replace-in-mysql)...