# copy the content of a table and paste it to another one

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to copy the content to an existing table to another existing table.
This is what I've tryed :

```
INSERT into memoryTable select * from currentTable
```

but I get this error message :
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'memoryTable.PRIMARY'

Comment: It means there is a Primary Key on your table and you are trying to insert an ID that already exists.

Comment: Ok but how can I do to not to adding data but just to replace data ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Why do you need to copy data between tables?

Comment: Depending on the dbms you are using you could use a MERGE statement or a combination of UPDATE and INSERT's

Comment: I'm on MySQL, I need to copy the data because the data of the 'currentTable' has to be replaced by recent data. But I also need to save it.

Comment: Unless you have gigabytes of data causing a performance problem, or some other sort of design mistake in your database, that shouldn't be necessary,  just to make way for more recent stuff

Answer (score 0):

For the persons who have the same problem, I've found a solution :

```
REPLACE
INTO memoryTable
SELECT *
FROM currentTable
;
```

Comment: fyi - If there is a duplicate/existing primary key, `replace` will overwrite values in `memoryTable` with the conflicting values from `currentTable`. If you would rather keep the existing values in `memoryTable`, you can use `insert ignore into memoryTable...`

See also [Difference between insert ignore and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723145/what-is-the-performance-difference-between-insert-ignore-and-replace-in-mysql)

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.