# update record if exists, else write new record?

Tags: php, mysql, upsert

I'm trying to execute this query and when it finds a record for $serial, it can update it. OR, if the serial doesn't exist, it can write a new record.

I get syntax erros but to me it seems fine. pretty darn sure ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is the way to go but i'm missing something...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `".$sys_id."` (serial, status) VALUES ('98745', 'active') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update if exists, insert if not (aka upsert or merge) in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to tell it what to update ([see manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html))

so:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `".$sys_id."` (serial, status) VALUES ('98745', 'active') 
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status=VALUES(active)";
```

(i am under the assumption that the key is `serial`)

Comment: If you are replicating to a lot of slaves this type of query can create problems on the replication thread.  In such cases you may need to break up the queries to reduce the size of the replicated bin logs.  Just something we have run into in the past.