# insert into mysql database, if records already exists, then update

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, upsert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update if exists, insert if not (aka upsert or merge) in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

how to insert into mysql database, if records already exists, then update...I know there is a solution on this page:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

**sib_table**

```
+=======================================================+
| sib_id | std_id  |  sib_name  |  sib_sex  |  sib_age  |
+=======================================================+
| 1      | 77      |  Sajjad    |   m       | 5/17/1990 |
| 1      | 77      |  Farah     |   f       | 9/14/1980 |
| 1      | 77      |  Bilal     |   m       | 1/10/1995 |
+=======================================================+
```

What sql would be if I want to add anther sibling to this table.

```
INSERT INTO sib_table
  (std_id,sib_name,sib_sex,sib_age) 
VALUES ('77','Sajjad','m','1/5/2010')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c = 3;

INSERT INTO sib_table
  (std_id,sib_name,sib_sex,sib_age) 
VALUES 
  ('77','Aamna','f','1/27/2005')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c = 3;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but you need to treat the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause just like an `UPDATE` statement. That means you need to setup a unique key so that trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO sib_table (std_id,sib_name,sib_sex,sib_age) 
VALUES ('77','Sajjad','m','1/5/2010')
```

... will only work **once**. Then you add the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause to change the rest of the fields (i.e. the ones that aren't part of the key) to match.

So, for example, assuming I read the table structure correctly, if you put a unique composite key on the columns `std_id` and `sib_name`, this will ensure that you can't add two siblings of the same name. And *that* means that when you go to add another like this:

```
INSERT INTO sib_table (std_id,sib_name,sib_sex,sib_age) 
VALUES ('77','Aamna','f','1/27/2005')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE sib_sex = 'f', sib_age = '1/27/2005'
```

... it will do one of two things:

1. add the new row if Aamna doesn't exist in family #77.
2. or update Aamna's sex and birthday if she's been added before.

This structure is more powerful than MySQL's `REPLACE` because it lets you do something different to the conflicting row than merely overwrite it with what you tried to insert. Of course, most of the time the functionality of `REPLACE` is what is actually wanted. But it is better to know the more generic statement.

Comment: ..Thank you very much for making me understand this query.. but how does this query knows... that its' only name that we don't need duplicate... 
... i think, if we update "name and sex" then duplication will be bound with age... right... ???

actually sib_id was to be.. 1, 2, 3 ... but wrote by mistake (1,1,1)

Comment: this method is only adding... not updating

Comment: If you do `ALTER TABLE sib_table ADD UNIQUE KEY (std_id, sib_name)` then you can't add a second sibling of the same name under the same std_id. Then the SQL I provided will update correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
REPLACE INTO sib_table (std_id,sib_name,sib_sex,sib_age) 
VALUES ('77','Aamna','f','1/27/2005')
```

Answer (score 0):

check number of rows in a case:

```
SELECT * where ...

if (number of rows == 0) {
   INSERT ...
} else {
   Update ...
}
```

Comment: but i want the "on duplicate key " feature

Comment: @jobsz.. in fact i want to learn the above INSERT INTO WITH UPDATES  statement... can you please help me in that...