# Update data if not exists, otherwise add to table

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update if exists, insert if not (aka upsert or merge) in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

I am creating a simple crawler gathering statistics from website. What I want to do is that if there is no record crawled from URL then insert to database, otherwise update the existing record, but I am not really sure how to do this without using php to

```
SELECT * from table where url='somevalue';
```

and if there is no record

```
INSERT INTO...
```

otherwise

```
UPDATE...
```

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL Manual :: INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: the problem is that url is not a unique key :/

Comment: Then make it one. There is no single query solution to this without such a constraint.

Comment: If i want to create a keyout of text column, it has to have a certain length which is not something I like (since the length can be pretty much random) not to mention that max length can be only 767 bytes

Comment: Store a hash of the URL in another column and use that as the key. Fixed length and with a proper hashing algorithm, unlikely to ever collide on two different URLs.

Comment: Yea i did similar thing. the website my script crawls also stores their unique id in a URL so I just extracted it with simple regexp and used a simple bigint as a unique key. works perfectly! Thank you!