# How to upsert two database tables with one SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, insert-update, upsert, mysql-insert-id

There are two database tables described in the following. The asterisk highlights the primary keys.

```
+----------------+    +----------------+
| posts          |    | url_references |
+----------------+    +----------------+
| id*            |    | url*           |
| post_content   |    | post_id        |
+----------------+    +----------------+
```

I want to ***insert* or *update* a *post*** based on the existence of the corresponding entry in the table *url_references*. What is the best **combination of SQL commands** to reach this? I would like to **avoid** to process the decision about *insert* or *update* in **PHP**.
The following scenarios describe the alternative step by step behavior using PHP commands.

```
SELECT * FROM url_references WHERE url = $url;
```

Scenario 1: Insert new entry.

```
// mysql_num_rows() returns 0
INSERT INTO post (post_content) VALUES ($postContent);
$postId = mysql_insert_id();
INSERT INTO url_references (url, post_id) VALUES ($url, $postId);
```

Scenario 2: Update existing entry.

```
// mysql_num_rows() returns 1
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rows);
$postId = $row['post_id'];
UPDATE posts SET post_content = $postContent WHERE id = post_id;
```

---

**Edit 1:** Note, that I cannot check for the *id* in *posts* directly! I want to manage (insert/update) *posts* based on their *url* as the primary key.

Comment: [How do I update if exists, insert if not (aka upsert or merge) in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

Comment: Yes, I read about it. But I have to deal with 2 tables.

Comment: @Vache: Good shot! I would add that without using MySQL-specific extensions one need to use [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) syntax, then to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` and then `COMMIT`. That would be a standard way of solving the task like this (`autocommit=off` of course).

Comment: @dma_k: Could you explain to me how you would use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` with my example? It sounds promising though I do not quite understand how to use it.

Comment: In some scenarios it might be a good option to move some of the logic to a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html).

Comment: In scenario 2, do you mean `$postId = $row['post_id'];`?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do above in a classical way, do the following.

First we may agree that `url` is a natural primary key. Anyway you need an index in this column to speedup your lookups:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX url_references_idx ON url_references(url);
```

After that if you execute:

```
INSERT INTO url_references (url) VALUES ($url);
```

you end up with two scenarios:

• The `INSERT` succeeds. That means your `$url` is new and you can proceed with:

```
INSERT INTO posts (id, post_content) values (NULL, $postContent);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); // This will return $post_id
UPDATE url_references SET post_id = $post_id WHERE url = $url;
COMMIT;
```

In this scenario the lock on newly inserted row in `url_references` guarantees that another thread will go the 2nd scenario, if 1st transaction is successfully committed (or 1st scenario if it fails).

• The `INSERT` fails. That means your `$url` is already known and you can proceed with:

```
SELECT post_id FROM url_references WHERE url = $url;
UPDATE posts SET post_content = $postContent WHERE id = $post_id;
COMMIT;
```

Note: The first `INSERT` statement guarantees that racing condition on `url_references` table is correctly handled provided you have enabled a correct transaction isolation level and `autocommit=off`.

Note: Using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` does not work in this case, as it will lock only existing rows (and we need to lock non-existing row, which is about to be inserted). Sorry if I confused you, please ignore my comment under your question.

Comment: Is there a way to pipe the result of `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` into the `UPDATE`query? I would like to avoid to process the `$post_id` via PHP since I do not really need it there.

Comment: Just try it and edit my post :) I will be happy to incorporate your improvements. I have also found a slight but critical error...

Comment: Thank you for edits. Still my question is: Can I avoid processing the result set of the `SELECT` in PHP?

Comment: One thing appears wrong to me: (1) you insert into table `url_references`, (2) you insert into table `posts`, (3) you ask for the `LAST_INSERT_ID`. --- The order should be 1-3-2 since the table `url_references` wants the `post_id`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You have stated that `url_references` does not have and id :) If you need it somewhere else in your application, that would be another `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`, so 1-3-2-3. But for above example it was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE INTO` to avoid deciding between `INSERT/UPDATE` on the `posts` table, then based on the number of rows affected by `REPLACE` determine whether you need to INSERT into url_references. Something like this:

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO posts (post_id, post_content) VALUES ($postId, $postContent)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($numRows == 1) {
    // was INSERT not DELETE/INSERT (UPDATE) - need to insert into url_references

    $postId = mysql_insert_id();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO url_references (url, post_id) VALUES ($url, $postId)";

    ... do SQL INSERT etc
}
```

From the MySQL `REPLACE` documentation:

> *The REPLACE statement returns a count to indicate the number of rows
>   affected. This is the sum of the rows deleted and inserted. If the
>   count is 1 for a single-row REPLACE, a row was inserted and no rows
>   were deleted. If the count is greater than 1, one or more old rows
>   were deleted before the new row was inserted.*

Note that I haven't tested the above pseudo-code, so you may have to tweak it.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html for reference.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have *post\_id* to run the `REPLACE` command.