# update if exists

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update if exists, insert if not (aka upsert or merge) in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

I have a table with the columns user, category and score. I want to run an insert that, if this user/category combination already exists instead just updates the score. Both the user and the category column can have the same value many times but each specific user/category combination may only exist on one single row. How can I do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this example, let's call your table scores:

Make sure you have a unique index

```
ALTER TABLE scores ADD UNIQUE INDEX user_category_ndx (user,category);
```

Now run this to replace:

```
INSERT INTO scores (user,category,score) VALUES ('username','mycat',127)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = VALUES(score);
```

If your updating the score means add up scores, then do this:

```
INSERT INTO scores (user,category,score) VALUES ('username','mycat',127)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = score + VALUES(score);
```

Give it a try!

**UPDATE 2011-08-28 09:00 EDT**

If you want to keep just high scores and then add the unique index, here is what you must do:

```
CREATE TABLE scores_new LIKE scores;
ALTER TABLE scores_new ADD UNIQUE INDEX user_category_ndx (user,category);
INSERT INTO scores_new (user,category,score)
SELECT user,category,MAX(score) FROM scores GROUP BY user,category;
ALTER TABLE scores RENAME scores_old;
ALTER TABLE scores_new RENAME scores;
#
# Drop old table if no longer needed
#
DROP TABLE scores_old;
```

**UPDATE 2011-08-28 10:53 EDT**

Run this to keep maximum score:

```
INSERT INTO scores (user,category,score) VALUES ('username','mycat',127)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = GREATEST(VALUES(score),score);
```

Comment: This seems just right but I can't add the unique index since lots of duplicate rows of this index already exists. Is there some way to delete the duplicates and only keep the row with the highest score? I tried to loop through all combinations but it did not work and I guess there must be a better way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your first answer as well as the update! This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Make sure you have a unique index defined on user, category. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html