# Insert and if it already exists update the columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, mobile) VALUES ('Karem', 'Parem', 'mail@mail.com', '123456789');
```

This what i would like to do, but if a row with the same email `mail@mail.com` already exists, then it should update that row with these values.

I found the http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html but I dont understand it

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? Have you tried it? What happened? What do you have so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update if exists, insert if not (aka upsert or merge) in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) to add a unique constraint on the `email` column then try this query:

```
INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, email, mobile)
VALUES ('Karem', 'Parem', 'mail@mail.com', '123456789')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    firstname = 'Karem',
    lastname = 'Parem',
    email = 'mail@mail.com', -- you can probably omit this
    mobile = '123456789'
```

Be careful though - if you have any other unique keys defined on your table (including the primary key, which is by definition unique) then they can also trigger the update.

Comment: How do i say that its the email that should look for unique? The email has a unique index with a indexname "uniq_email"

Comment: I dont get it. First you say use alter table to make it unique and now you say that i cant check for email anymore because its unique index?

Comment: @Karem: How many unique indexes do you have on your table? If you only have one then there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You achieve this goal by using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) but IMHO checking the existence of the primary key before inserting/updating is more appropriate as:

- triggers may lead to concurrency issue, the 'insert or update' can use a transaction to shield from such issues
- your code will be more readable
- it will be more efficient