# Checking if variable data already exist in databse

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I am trying to follow this previously answered question [How to check if value already exists in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015098/how-to-check-if-value-already-exists-in-mysql-database)

Here is my code

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect(Localhost,"mwtwoone_xbl","password","mwtwoone_xbl");
mysql_select_db( 'mwtwoone_xbl' );

$txn_id = $_GET['txn'];

echo $txn_id;

$checktxnID = mysql_query("SELECT txn_id from codes WHERE txn_id = '$txn_id'");

if (!$checktxnID) {
    die('Query failed to execute for some reason');
}

if (mysql_num_rows($checktxnId) > 0) {
echo "User id exists already.";
$user = mysql_fetch_array($checktxnId);
print_r($user); // the data returned from the query
}

echo "User id doesnt exist";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

$txn_id will be defined and I simply need to check if its value is already in table codes on column txn_id. Thanks for all the help, it is very appreciated.

Now when I access URL .php?txn=123
I get 123User id doesnt exist already.
The problem is, multiple rows on table codes columb txn_id contain value 123!

Comment: Ooooh. I want to be first to say that mysql_* functions are deprecated. :)

Comment: And? Any errors? What's the question?

Comment: Ahh yes so sorry, updated the original post.

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` to your query.

Comment: Do read up on this, you're wide open to injection => http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1415724

Comment: So now does my new query look like $checktxnID = mysql_query("SELECT txn_id from codes WHERE txn_id = '$txn_id' LIMIT 1");   I am still getting the same page 123User id doesn't exist already.

Answer (score 3):

You've used `$checktxnId` rather than `$checktxnID` in your conditional `> 0`check.

Comment: Damn it I can't believe this past hour of frustration was because of that small error, thank you so much.

Comment: And that's why I **never never never** use any mixed letter case. Too much room for typo errors. I always use underscores as a seperator.   @user3029524

Comment: @user3029524 I suggest that you always turn on error report. `error_report(E_ALL)`. refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- camelCase for variables and under_scores for array keys are a basic coding standard. His problem is _not_ using a proper IDE: NetBeans (free), phpStorm (paid)...among other things.

Comment: You have a point there. @keyboardSmasher I'm "Old School" myself ;-)

Answer (score -2):

try to change this line

```
$checktxnID = mysql_query("SELECT txn_id from codes WHERE txn_id = '$txn_id'");
```

to

```
$checktxnID = mysql_query("SELECT txn_id from codes WHERE txn_id = '".$txn_id."'");
```

Comment: Just did that, still getting the same message!

Comment: Using double quotes, so variable value will be interpolated

Comment: Should I switch around double/single quotes?

Comment: No, either single quotes with concatenation or double quotes for interpolation. (so leave as is, though you are injecting user input which is of course bad)