# How to check if a data exist in database in PHP? (MULTIPLE)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a registeration form with the if statement:

```
$query = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($query_run)==1) 
{
    echo "Username already exist.";
}
```

The thing i want to do is checking also the "email" and "nickname" if they exist in database.
How can i do that?

Comment: `OR` operator is your friend

Comment: Where should i use the `OR` operator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if value already exists in MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015098/how-to-check-if-value-already-exists-in-mysql-database)

Comment: Also you need to use double quotes for the variable

Comment: Why do you throw mud to my question :D @Nouphal.M ty mate i tried it and it worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a row exists in MySQL? (i.e. check if an email exists in MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/how-to-check-if-a-row-exists-in-mysql-i-e-check-if-an-email-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT `username`, `email`, `nickname`
FROM `users`
WHERE (`username` = '$username' OR
       `email` = '$username' OR
       `nickname` = '$username' )
```

Comment: I solved it by myself... :P But anyway: Clear code... Thanks!

Comment: Why * instead of just username, he/she just want to know whether user already exists or not

Answer (score 1):

You should not use plain **mysql_query**

To quote php.net

> **Warning** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be
> removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension
> should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ
> for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
> mysqli_query() PDO::query()

Try using PDO or mysqli.
This is essential to prevent mysql injections.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Here is an example for how to do this with PDO

```
$config['db'] = array(
    'host'          => 'localhost',
    'username'      => 'username',
    'password'      => 'password',
    'dbname'        => 'dbname'
    );



$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$config['db']['host']};dbname={$config['db']['dbname']}",
              $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$users = $stmt->fetchAll()

$username = 'Bob';
$email = 'bob@gmail.com';
$nickname = 'BobTheMan';

foreach($users as $user)
{
    if($user['username'] == $username)
    {
        // there is a user by this username
    }
    if($user['email'] == $email)
    {
        // there is a user by this email
    }
    if($user['nickname'] == $nickname)
    {
        // there is a user by this nickname
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use prepared statements. And mysql_* has been deprecated
2. SELECT * instead of SELECT 'username' vill return you whole row and you can check all fields

Comment: Why * instead of just `username`, he/she just want to know whether user already exists or not

Comment: oh... after reading i thought that he wants to know if those fiedls are populated not that he wants to check username against those fields )

Comment: Bhavik Shah, he also want to know how to check if "email" and "nickname" exists in the database, and if he just grabs username, then email, then nickname he'll run 3 queries to the DB instead of grabbing all columns and then looping through them with PHP (with 1 querie)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  print_r($result);
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// sql injection friendly code! *here*
$query = "SELECT `username` FROM `users`
    WHERE '$username' IN (`username`, `email`, `nickname`) LIMIT 1;";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($query_run) == 1){
    echo "Username already exist.";
}
```

I assume values are unique in `users` as you do `== 1`. Otherwise change `== 1` to `> 0` and remove `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score -1):

Expanding what Nouphal said.

```
$query = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username'=$username OR 'email' = $email";
```