# If (SELECT...) = 0 INSERT . in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement, subquery

I am used to doing this in sql server

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column1=@value1) = 0
INSERT INTO table(column1, column2, column3) VALUES(@value1, @value2, @value3)
```

But I can't really get it to work in MySql. Please help :)

---------------- EDIT ------------------

There shouldn't be a lot of fuss or magic involved in this, I would assume.

```
If an e-mail does not exist in a table then insert several values into that table.
```

That's it. Preferbly a one liner, to embed in programming code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update if exists, insert if not (aka upsert or merge) in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

Comment: Is it complete query? Or just a column ? If its a column then put your complete query.

Comment: regarding your edit: read  my answer below :-) no magic involved

Comment: link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

another way to do this is using the `INSERT IGNORE` statement. Assuming `column1` should only hold unique values, you can add a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint on the field (if its not your primary key already):

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE KEY column1 (column1)
```

you can then write your query as such:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table(column1, column2, column3) VALUES(@value1, @value2, @value3)
```

or if you want to automatically update the other fields, use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO table(column1, column2, column3) VALUES(@value1, @value2, @value3) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column2 = @value2,  column3 = @value3
```

letting the database handle it automatically using unique key has several advantages:

- better performance and scalability through usage of indexes as opposed to full table scans
- failsafe - you can not add two rows with same unique identifier accidentally with a wrong query
- better readability of your queries

NOTE: a unique key may also span multiple rows. stupid example: combination of "ip" and "port" may be combined as the unique identifier "connection".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, the e-mail is not unique. The only unique field and key is an auto incremented ID

Comment: but it seems in your question that you try to prevent multiple entries for the same email address ... defining it unique sounds like the correct solution?

Comment: ha ha... granted :D The DB is a little messy, and I don't want to make it worse, I suppose. LOL

Comment: this can only make it better, not worse :-) i would use the chance to correct things here. just my 2 cents

Comment: OK @Kaii. I cleaned up, it wasn't so bad, and I applied the unique attribute and insert ignore. So Now everything should be great.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it like this:

```
Declare @count INT;
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column1=@value1);
IF (@count = 0)
INSERT INTO table(column1, column2, column3) VALUES(@value1, @value2, @value3)
```