# overwrite mysql table data

Tags: mysql, sql, web-crawler

I have a web crawler. The web crawler gathers the links from web pages I give it but when it is retrieving the links, some links are duplicated due to the website. is there a way in MYSQL to overwrite data if a new row is the exact same as an old row.

Say if I have http://www.facebook.com in a link field

I also manage to pick up http://www.facebook.com again, I would like the latter to overwrite the old row. therefore I don't have clashes on my search engine.

Comment: [Helpful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want to update a `last_updated` date if the `url` already exists. Else there is no good reason to do an update.

```
 INSERT INTO `scrapping_table`
    (`url`)
    VALUES
    ("www.facebook.com")
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `date_updated` = `datetime.now()`
```

Comment: i have the table, 'pages' and can you explain that a bit more

Comment: So your `pages` table has a column `url` which stores the `facebook.com`. Now you are crawling the web again and your crawler finds `facebook.com` again. Updating the `url` now is a redundant step unless of course you can store some more meta information about this new crawling by storing the `date` you performed this update.

Comment: In larger systems like Google, crawling can take a few weeks and storing the `last time I saw this url` information is useful to the search algorithm and so that the crawler does not keep going over the same urls. On a slightly different note, Google uses `inverted indices` which is a good strategy for building a full-text search.

Answer (score 1):

look into `ON DUPLICATE KEY` actions

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Basically make the columns you're concerned with a unique key write your insert statement and then add

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col = overwriting value
```

Answer (score 0):

If your link field is unique than you can use

```
 INSERT INTO "mytable" (link_field, x_column, y_column) VALUES ("www.facebook.com",'something new for x','something new for y')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE x_column='something new for x', y_column='something new for y'
```

Just make sure your link field is unique and if you have more unique fields in your column, I suggest use this second method because [they](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) suggest avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.

1. set your link field as unique.
2. before inserting a row try

   ```
   Select "primary_id" from mytable where link_field="www.facebook.com"
   ```
3. Count the number of returned row from this SQL.

   =>If count>0 then UPDATE the row using the "primary_id" we just grabbed through the SELECT SQL

   => if count==0 , just insert your row

Answer (score 0):

**beware!!**

while operating a web crawler that probably will find millions of links 
you want to minimize the query's each "crawl" process fires...
do you want to create a unique link table that will feed the bots? or do you want to prevent duplicate search results?

**unique url pool table:**

- while crawling the page - you should save url's to an array (or list) and making sure (!in_array()) that the its a unique value array, you will find that each page you crawl includes alot of repeated links - so clean them before using sql.
- covert the urls to hashes ("simhash" of 32 digits [1,0]).
- now open a connection to db and check if exists if it does dump them! don't update (its making a second process). you should match the links using the hashes over an indexed table it will be far more faster.

**prevent duplicate results search:**

- if you indexed the url in the above methodology you should not find duplicate url's, if you have, it means there is a problem in your crawling operation.
- even if you have duplicate values in another table and you want to search it but not returning duplicate results you can use DISTINCT in your query.

good luck!