# Update if exist, insert if not exist

Tags: mysql, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update if exists, insert if not (aka upsert or merge) in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

I have program that can do batch updating price for booking engine.

example user input for to do update batch the price is like this

```
$dateStart = '2012-12-01';
$dataEnd = '2012-12-31';
$hotelId = 1;
$price = 300000;
```

And database is like this

```
id | date       | hotelId | price
1  | 2012-12-01 | 1       | 100000
```

How should the MySQL Query, to do batch update and insert with condition if `date` and `hotelId` is already exist then do update, but if not exist do insert?

I understand if doing looping day by day and checking if data exist or not in PHP will be really spend much memory.

```
for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++){...}
```

I'm looking solution how it can be done with single/any mysql query that can save computer resource.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement.

It will require that you have a UNIQUE or PRIMARY compound index on the `date` and `hotelId` columns so that the DUPLICATE KEY condition is triggered.

Comment: How to create unique compound index?

Comment: @GusDeCooL - Simple: `ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE KEY (date, hotelId)`. See the [docs on `ALTER TABLE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html).