# Mysql compare two columns in two tables

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, relational-database

I have 2 tables, namely Products & Purchase:

```
products: id, productname, quantityleft.

purchase:id, productname, quantity.
```

**PRODUCTS TABLE**- will get all NEW products purchased. Meaning no same productname will exist in table prroducts. List of all unique Products

**PURCHASE TABLE**-list of all purchase products with unique Purchase_ID.

Here is my scenarios/problems:

- If ever i want to add or insert values in **PURCHASE**, the table **PRODUCTS** will get all the values of **purchase** BUT only if *productname* in **purchase** is not existing in 'productname' in PRODUCTS.
- If the *productname* **purchase** is already existed in *productname* **products** then the *quantity* in **products** will be added by the value of *quantity* in **purchase** having the same *productname*.

So far I have not met this situation before but maybe if I got this one it would be easy for me to code this. What I am thinking right now is to use the `distinct` but i know this is not the right thing to do. Can you suggest me the best and right way to achieve this one? Aside from I am really clueless, I can't googled it. Hope you could help me.

Comment: This is called an "UPSERT".  Here is a similar question which has a good answer if you have a primary key on the product table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql

Comment: upsert is applicable in two tables too?

Answer (score 1):

Well I will do at following way
Change the Scenario,

```
products: id, productname.  
purchase: id, productname, quantity, prd_id.
```

Item purchased; check **whether name exist in products**
If not exist
 - assign new **product id**
 - Insert to **products** and **purchase** table.
Else if existing item purchased (check products id)
 - Nothing to **products** table
 - Update **quantity+currentQty** at **purchase** `where prd_id =
   products.id`