# Mysql. INSERT, UPDATE and WHERE

Tags: mysql, where-clause, insert-update

I'm needing to create a query that update if the `some know value` exists or create a register if not.

I tried some variations like this below, but I can't put it to work.

How can I do this?

Attemp:

```
UPDATE OR INSERT
    mytable
SET
    attribute1 = 'value1',
    attribute2 = 'value2',
    attribute3 = 'some known value'
WHERE
    attribute3 = 'some known value'
```

Comment: It's called an "upsert".  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql/1218909#1218909

Comment: What do you mean by "create a register"?

Comment: Are you looking for an [upsert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)?

Answer (score 1):

@GarouDan your passing only for update query no insert query use below code like this..
first find is there any record with attribute3='some known value'..for that use like this..

```
declare xattribute text;
select attribute3 into xsttribute where attribute3 = 'some known value'
if found
UPDATE  mytable
SET
    attribute1 = 'value1',
    attribute2 = 'value2',
    attribute3 = 'some known value'
WHERE
    attribute3 = 'some known value'
else
 insert into mytable(attribute1 ,attribute3 ,attribute3 ) values (value1,value2,some known value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the MySQL command REPLACE is what you are looking for. An example:

```
replace into cars (color,crashed) values ('black',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysql's INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html