# Modify insert into to update

Tags: php, mysql, insert, insert-into

I want to modify my code so instead of just inserting a new row in the MySQL table, it can check to see if there is one with the same item number, and update it.

php code

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","inventory");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
      {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }



     $sql = "INSERT INTO `current stock` (ItemNumber, Stock)
               VALUES
             ('".$_POST['ItemNumber']."', '".$_POST['Stock']."' )";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }
     echo "1 record added";


     mysqli_close($con);
     ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax,

```
$sql = "
   INSERT INTO `current stock` (ItemNumber, Stock)
   VALUES ('$_POST[ItemNumber]', '$_POST[Stock]' )
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   Stock = '$_POST[Stock]'
";
```

`ItemNumber` should be primary/unique key in this case