# Add new row if there is new data?

Tags: php

My current DB query overwrites the row, I am trying to add a new row if a column in that row changes, let me show an example.

**This is the row.** When post_id changes id like a new row for that id

[image: row]

**This is what happens when the id changes**, it overwrites.. instead id like a new row created..

[image]

Here is the function that INSERTS the data and UPDATES

```
 //This is the INSERT
 // Execute query
        $wpdb->query(
            $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $table_name
                                (post_id, name, data, date_c, date_m)
                            VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %d, %d)",
                            '',
                            '',
                            time(),
                            time()
                            )
        );


  //This is the UPDATE
  // DB data
    $post_id = $wpdb->escape($alldata['postid']['thepostid']);
    $name = $wpdb->escape($alldata['properties']['title']);
    $data = $wpdb->escape(json_encode($alldata));

    // Update
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table_name SET
                post_id = '$post_id',
                name = '$name',
                data = '$data',
                date_m = '".time()."'
              ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

It's a submit function, when the form is submitted the row is inserted or updated, I am clueless as to how I would write it to say, if NEW post_id INSERT NEW row... Hoping someone can help me write that query and give some advice...

**UPDATE:**

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method="post" class="wrap" id="ls-slider-form">  

    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">


             <!-- Global Settings -->
        <div class="ls-page ls-post-id" style="display: block;">
        <div id="post-body-content">
           <div id="titlediv">
               <div id="titlewrap">
                   <input type="text" name="thepostid" value="<?php echo the_ID() ?>">
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

  <input type="submit" /> 

 </form>


function brash_add_settings() {


     // Add slider
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    // Get WPDB Object
    global $wpdb;

    // Table name
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "brash";


        // Execute query
        $wpdb->query(
            $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $table_name
                                (post_id, name, data, date_c, date_m)
                            VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %d, %d)",
                            '',
                            '',
                            time(),
                            time()
                            )
        );

        // Empty slider
        $alldata = array();

        // ID
        $id = mysqli_insert_id();


        $alldata['properties'] = $_POST['alldata']['properties'];
        $alldata['postid'] = $_POST['brash-post-id']['postid'];


    // DB data
    $post_id = $wpdb->escape($alldata['postid']['thepostid']);
    $name = $wpdb->escape($alldata['properties']['title']);
    $data = $wpdb->escape(json_encode($alldata));

    // Update
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table_name SET
                post_id = '$post_id',
                name = '$name',
                data = '$data',
                date_m = '".time()."'
              ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

    // Echo last ID for redirect
    echo $id;

    die();
}



 }
```

Comment: In wordpress wp_postmeta they do something similar to what I am trying to achieve, I see what you're saying but in this case its necessary. Could you show a simple example, I cant quite picture how I would check if ID has been passed...

Comment: Yes I see what you're trying to do now... Can you post sample markup of your form, to see which data are you sending and how your update function is being called?

Comment: Sorry someone was at the door.. I updated the OP to be more full.. there is the form and the function that posts the data.. there is obviously ajax involved.. but I am more focused on changing the insert query so that it adds new row if the `$post_id` data changes

Comment: I think this is normally called an 'upsert'

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1218905/2049063) for an example of 'upsert'

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy. You can use jquery.post or ajax. If you want to use submit: add hidden element and set it value to update or insert related your decision.