# Insert or update if already exists - prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, upsert

I have found answers all over the place on how to INSERT or UPDATE if record already exists, a good approach is using the `on duplicate key update` or REPLACE, but I can't seem to find anywhere how to do this using a prepared statement. Is this possible?

EDIT:

Ok let me be more specific with my question:

If I have a mysqli prepared statement like this example:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE test SET name= ?, age= ? WHERE iduser= ?")) {    
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $name, $age, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

In this case how can I build a `on duplicate key update`
This is were Im stuck, I dont know how to use the "?" :

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (iduser, name, age) VALUES (?,?,?))){
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=?,age=?")) {    
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $id, $name, $age);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: depends on your flavour of SQL.

Comment: And I would rather not use REPLACE if possible

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update if exists, insert if not (aka upsert or merge) in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

Comment: Aron, my question is regarding a Prepared Statement, you are pointing to the answers I have already seen :-/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: is this a JAVA question? Please tag accordingly. Parameterized queries are just SQL queries that you...parameterize. Just swap out the parameters in your query with your selected language's token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be missing something, but can you not just update the second bindParam to: `$stmt->bind_param('issss', $id, $name, $age, $name, $age)`?

If you don't know how the question marks work and are just copy/pasting code examples, I suggest you read up on [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or look into [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).