# MySQL Syntax error for IF ... INSERT INTO

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this query in my application:

```
string sql = @"UPDATE AccountGroup
            SET IdGroup = @idGroup
            WHERE IdAccount = @idAccount;

            IF (ROW_COUNT() = 0) THEN
                INSERT INTO AccountGroup (IdAccount, IdGroup)
                VALUES (@idAccount, @idGroup);
            END IF;"
```

Which gives me this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (ROW_COUNT() = 0) THEN INSERT INTO AccountGroup (IdAccount, IdGroup)' at line 1.

What is the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you are using SQL Server syntax, and even think you are using Microsoft's SQL Server, when the database you are running the query against is actually MySQL, which is a completely different platform from a completely different vendor.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Nice catch. The OP apparently didn't notice the "MySQL" in the error message. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand You're right, that completely flew over me. I've changed the syntax but I can't figure out what's wrong with it now.

Comment: @idlackage Post your updated query.

Comment: @Mansfield It's been posted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update if exists, insert if not (aka upsert or merge) in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a MySQL server handy to test this.  That said, is it possible that you're using `IF()`  when you want to use `IF`?

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) for `IF()`

> IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
>
> If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns expr2; otherwise it returns expr3. IF() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

And from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html) for `IF`

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
   [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
   [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

Which would make me think you want to write the code as something like

```
string sql = @"UPDATE AccountGroup
            SET IdGroup = @idGroup
            WHERE IdAccount = @idAccount;

            IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
                INSERT INTO AccountGroup (IdAccount, IdGroup)
                VALUES (@idAccount, @idGroup);
            END IF;"
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems like it would be the problem. I'm still getting a syntax error near that part however--any chance this could be written as a case statement?

Comment: Does this query do what you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql.  If so I'll vote to close as a dupe.