# MYSQL php Select if not exists doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, insert

When my DB holds the data already it should echo "fail"

my Code is :

```
   if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO name(username, passwort, email, active, loc, image)
  VALUES ('$name', '$pass','$mail' , 0, '$loc', 'mo.png')"))
  {      

 echo "fail";
  }else{
  echo "sucess";

  }
```

the weird thing is if my Username ecist it do what it should do, no insert.
But my echo "fail" is not called, but why?

Comment: Why use `INSERT IGNORE`?

Answer (score 0):

Very, very simply: "insert ignore" doesn't generate an error - so your "fail" never occurs.

Suggestion: one alternative might be to try "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".

Here is the man page:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Here are more details:

[How do I update if exists, insert if not (AKA "upsert" or "merge") in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)