# Update MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am getting values of a business by the API and inserting it into a database.

```
SNO       ID            category
1              aaa         Machine learning
2              aaa         AI
3              bbb        mobile
```

Where SNO is the primary key which is set to auto increment.
Now after 2 days, for keeping my database up to date I need to get the new data from the API.
So suppose that I come to know that ID ‘aaa’ now has one more category as “data structures”

Question:
How can I update my table to reflect this new category?
I am expecting something like

```
SNO       ID            category
1              aaa         Machine learning
2              aaa         AI
3              bbb        mobile
4              aaa         data structures
```

I don’t know the SNO as they are Auto Incremented. 
Deleting all the rows which has ID = “aaa”  and then Inserting it again is one option but I am trying to avoid that  as it might increase the overheads.

I am getting new values from the API,

So I am getting Machine learning, AI and Data structures ( all 3 )
If I use , so in my code when I iterate over the category variable 3 SQL Will be generated

```
INSERT INTO tablename (ID, category) VALUES ('aaa', ‘Machine learning’);
INSERT INTO tablename (ID, category) VALUES ('aaa', ‘AI’);
INSERT INTO tablename (ID, category) VALUES ('aaa', 'data structures');
```

So in this case 1st and 2nd insert statement will be duplicated, my table will have duplicate rows
.
.

I basically need to check if the ID and Category  exists in the BD if they do not then INSERT ?( The Primary Key SNO is set to auto Increment)

```
+ Options                       

Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra   
uuid    varchar(50) NO      NULL        
categoryName    varchar(50) NO      NULL        
sno int(5)  NO  PRI NULL
```

Comment: It seems MySQL support merge, with nonstandard syntax ; check http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/09/30/how-to-do-an-upsert-in-mysql/

Comment: Why don't you use simple `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 2):

If you just insert the new "data structures" row, it will have the next auto-incremented number, which in your case would likely be 4.  The only time it wouldn't be 4 is if you inserted some rows and deleted them, which would cause the auto increment counter to be higher.  You could just insert the row like this:

> INSERT INTO tablename (ID, category) VALUES ('aaa', 'data
>   structures');

Or maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly.  If not reply back and I'll try to help.

Comment: I am getting new values from the API,

So I am getting Machine learning, AI and Data structures ( all 3 )
If I use , so in my code when I iterate over the category variable 3 SQL Will be generated
INSERT INTO tablename (ID, category) VALUES ('aaa', ‘Machine learning’);
INSERT INTO tablename (ID, category) VALUES ('aaa', ‘AI’);
INSERT INTO tablename (ID, category) VALUES ('aaa', 'data structures');


So in this case 1st and 2nd insert statement will be duplicated, my table will have duplicate rows

Comment: I'd probably need to know more about the API you are using.  However, you have a couple of options.  You could always query the table to see if a row already exists (SELECT FROM tablename WHERE ID='aaa' AND category='data structures') and if there's no match, insert.  If you post more details about how the API works maybe we can come up with a better solution for you.

Comment: Yes, I need to check if its in the Database and if doesn't exist then Insert. What would that SQL look like?  

INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY will take into consideration the primary key ? but my primary key is the SNO and not the business ID

Comment: I think INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY should work, as long as the business ID (your id column) is also a unique key.  If that is the case, this SQL should work for you (sorry one sec, getting used to the stackoverflow comment system)

Comment: `INSERT INTO tablename (ID, category) VALUES ('aaa', 'data structures') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=ID` would probably work.  Not sure if it's the most elegant solution.  But basically this would insert a row, or if it exists, essentially do nothing (set the ID to the value of ID).

Comment: And of course, this assumes that the ID column is a unique key.  If you want to figure that out, run the SQL `DESC tablename` which will dump out the table structure, and post it here.

Comment: Updated the question which the table structure. In this case would ON Duplicate Key work? sno and uuid are both unique in my case.

Comment: @AdiMathur, it won't work as your table is structured right now.  However, run this to make the uuid / categoryName combination unique : `ALTER TABLE tableName ADD UNIQUE INDEX (uuid, categoryName);`.  Then when you run updates, run them like this : `INSERT INTO tableName (uuid, categoryName) VALUES ('aaa', 'data structures') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uuid=uuid;` I just tested this out on SQLFiddle and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply    `INSER` the new row by background checking or [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [`UPDATE` if exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)