# Speed up MySQL Update/Insert Statement

Tags: python, mysql

How can I improve the following function from a speed point of view? Ideally, I'd like this to use executemany as part of this up process.

While the function works fine, I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this; check if a value exists and update/insert as applicable.

I need to do this daily across millions of data.

```
def insert_or_update(self, profile_id, landing_page, keyword, position, impressions, clicks, ctr):
    ''' checks if a entry exists, if not it's inserted. If it is, the metrics
    are updated.
    '''
    try:
        self.cursor.execute('select id, position, impressions, clicks, ctr from temp where profile_id={} and keyword="{}" and landing_page="{}"'.format(profile_id, keyword, landing_page))
        data = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if data:
            row_id = data[0]
            sql_impressions = data[2] + impressions
            sql_clicks = data[3] + clicks
            sql_ctr = sum([data[4], ctr]) / len([data[4], ctr])
            # if the keyword/landing_page exists
            self.cursor.execute("update temp set position={}, impressions={}, clicks={}, ctr={} where id={}".format(position, sql_impressions, sql_clicks, sql_ctr, row_id))
            # Commit your changes in the database
            self.db.commit()
            return self.cursor.lastrowid
        else:
            # if the keyword/landing_page doesn't exist
            self.cursor.execute("insert into temp (profile_id, landing_page, keyword, position, impressions, clicks, ctr) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (profile_id, landing_page, keyword, position, impressions, clicks, ctr))
            # Commit your changes in the database
            self.db.commit()
            return self.cursor.lastrowid
    except Exception as e:
        return e
        # Rollback in case there is any error
        self.db.rollback()
    finally:
        self.db.close()
```

Comment: Don't close the database connection every time?

Comment: What is `sql_ctr = sum([data[4], ctr]) / len([data[4], ctr])` supposed to be doing? As near as I can tell it's just `(data[4] + ctr) / 2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a bunch of performance problems here if you need to do this millions of times.

- You're preparing the same SQL statement over and over again, millions of times. It would work better to prepare it once and execute it millions of times.
- You're disconnecting from the database on every function call after a single query. That means you need to reconnect each time and any cached information is thrown away. Don't do that, leave it connected.
- You're committing after each row. This will slow things down. Instead, commit after doing a batch.
- The select + update or insert can probably be done as a single upsert.
- That you're inserting so much into a temp table is probably a performance issue.
- If the table has too many indexes that can slow inserts. Sometimes it's best to drop indexes, do a big batch update, and recreate them.
- Because you're putting values directly into your SQL, your SQL is open to a [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

---

Instead...

- Use prepared statements and bind parameters
- Leave the database connected
- Do updates in bulk
- Only commit at the end of a run of updates
- Do all the math in the `UPDATE` rather then `SELECT + math + UPDATE`.
- Use an "UPSERT" instead of `SELECT` then `UPDATE` or `INSERT`

First off, prepared statements. These let MySQL compile the statement once and then reuse it. The idea is you write a statement with placeholders for the values.

```
select id, position, impressions, clicks, ctr
from temp
where profile_id=%s and
      keyword=%s and 
      landing_page=%s
```

Then you execute that with the values as arguments, not as part of the string.

```
self.cursor.execute(
   'select id, position, impressions, clicks, ctr from temp where profile_id=%s and keyword=%s and landing_page=%s',
   (profile_id, keyword, landing_page)
)
```

This allows the database to cache the prepared statement and not have to recompile it each time. It also avoids a SQL injection attack where a clever attacker can craft a value that is actually more SQL like `" MORE SQL HERE "`. It is a very, very, very common security hole.

Note, you might need to use [MySQL's own Python database library to get true prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html). Don't worry about it too much, using prepared statements is not your biggest performance problem.

---

Next, what you're basically doing is adding to an existing row, or if there is no existing row, inserting a new one. This can be done more efficiently in a single statement with an `UPSERT`, a combined `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. [MySQL has it as `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql#1218909).

To see how this is done, we can write your `SELECT then UPDATE` as a single `UPDATE`. The calculations are done in the SQL.

```
    update temp
    set impressions = impressions + %s,
        clicks = clicks + %s,
        ctr = (ctr + %s / 2)
    where profile_id=%s and
          keyword=%s and
          landing_page=%s
```

Your INSERT remains the same...

```
    insert into temp
        (profile_id, landing_page, keyword, position, impressions, clicks, ctr)
        values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

Combine them into one INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

```
    insert into temp
        (profile_id, landing_page, keyword, position, impressions, clicks, ctr)
        values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    on duplicate key update
    update temp
    set impressions = impressions + %s,
        clicks = clicks + %s,
        ctr = (ctr + %s / 2)
```

This depends on what the keys of the table are defined as. If you have `unique( profile_id, landing_page, keyword )` then it should work the same as your code.

Even if you can't do the upsert, you can eliminate the `SELECT` by trying the `UPDATE`, checking if it updated anything, and if it didn't doing an `INSERT`.

---

Do the updates in bulk. Instead of calling a subroutine which does one update and commits, pass it a big list of things to be updated and work on them in a loop. You can even take advantage of [`executemany`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany) to run the same statement with multiple values. Then commit.

You might be able to do the `UPSERT` in bulk. `INSERT` can take multiple rows at once. For example, this inserts three rows.

```
insert into whatever
    (foo, bar, baz)
values (1, 2, 3),
       (4, 5, 6), 
       (7, 8, 9)
```

You can likely do the same with your `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` reducing the amount of overhead to talk to the database. See [this post for an example](http://blog.cnizz.com/2010/05/31/optimize-mysql-queries-fast-mutliple-row-inserts/) (in PHP, but you should be able to adapt).

This sacrifices returning the ID of the last inserted row, but them's the breaks.

Comment: Thanks mate, that's a lot for me to go off and keep me busy!! :)

Comment: on insert there is 7 values but only 3 for the update, how would you pass both sets in?

Comment: I've sorted it - Just want to say thanks again. It's running like the clappers now!

Comment: @Adders You probably figured out that the duplicate key (which can be multi column) acts like a where clause for the update. That's why you'd probably need to define a multi part unique key. Glad you got it sorted!