# Efficient way to check if composite key exists before inserting

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql Nodejs package but I will tag this question as mysql only as people with mysql knowledge should be able to help me out.

This question is more about finding an efficient way to write a query.

I have a table with a composite key of `partID`,`orderID` and `stageID`.

I need to insert into this table if there are no previous composite key else update the other fields if a row with these composite keys were found.

I was going to do a select query where condition of these 3 columns and then in case of a result do an update else do an insert.

Is this the best way to handle this situation. Sorry I do not have much experience with SQL databases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update if exists, insert if not (AKA "upsert" or "merge") in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the composite key as `unique` or create a unique index on them:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_3 unique (partID, orderID stageID);
```

If you attempt to insert a row with duplicate keys, then you will get an error.  If you want to avoid the error, use `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into t (partID, orderID, stageID, . . .)
    values (?, ?, ?, . . .)
    on duplicate key update partID = values(partID);
```

The set in the `on duplicate key` does not do anything except prevent a duplicate error.