# Insert row into table if it is empty and replace the existing row if it isn't in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite 3:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
bar TEXT
);
```

It always has 0 or 1 rows. I want to write a query which updates the row if there is 1 row and adds the row if there are 0. What is the cleanest way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717590/sqlite-upsert-on-duplicate-key-update), giving the table a primary key, and using the `INSERT OR IGNORE` syntax, always using the same key value.

Answer (score 3):

if you could add one more unique field, then you can:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO foo (id, bar) VALUES (1, ?);
```

the table creation is in this case:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER NOT NULL, bar TEXT, UNIQUE (id));
```

or as Alexey found it out, *without* the primary key:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO foo (rowid, bar) VALUES (1, ?);
```

Comment: No, actually it doesn't. It deletes already present data instead of updating it.

Comment: it replaces the actual data with the new one. isn't it what you've asked for?

Comment: If there are two columns, and I want to update one, the other will be set to default value.

Comment: you haven't mentioned this in the O.P.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo) = 0  
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('text')  
    END  
ELSE  
    BEGIN  
        UPDATE foo SET baa = 'text' 
    END
```

Hope this helps.