# How to copy data from one table to another (where both have other fields too that are not in common)?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables `Source` and `Destination` that have the same fields. `ID` and `COUNTRY`, though they both have other fields too that are not in common.

I need to copy the `Source.Country` value to the `Destination.Country` where the join is on `ID`. I can't make SQLite do this. In SQL Server this is a super simple task.

Comment: Would it be something a little like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717590/sqlite-upsert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: Data Corruption Warning - If you are renaming tables at any point, there are certain patterns that risk corrupting table references in triggers, views, and foreign keys.

As explicitly stated in the SQLite docs, Section 7 of https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html, the following steps may cause corruption:

1. Rename old tables
2. Create new table
3. Copy data
4. Drop old tables.

The docs also explicitly lay out the recommended steps. Here is the summary from the docs:
1. Create new table
2. Copy data
3. Drop old table
4. Rename new into old

Answer (score 191, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Destination SELECT * FROM Source;
```

See [SQL As Understood By SQLite: INSERT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) for a formal definition.

Comment: Not a valid answer because the question contain "though they both have other fields too that are not in common."  
End from SQLite manual: "If no column-list is specified, the number of columns in the result of the SELECT must be the same as the number of columns in the table".

Answer (score 17):

If you have data already present in both the tables and you want to update a table  column values based on some condition then use this

```
UPDATE Table1 set Name=(select t2.Name from Table2 t2 where t2.id=Table1.id)
```

Comment: Doing this will wipe data from table1 if table2 has fewer rows than table1.

Answer (score 9):

I've been wrestling with this, and I know there are other options, but I've come to the conclusion the safest pattern is:

```
create table destination_old as select * from destination;

drop table destination;

create table destination as select
d.*, s.country
from destination_old d left join source s
on d.id=s.id;
```

It's safe because you have a copy of `destination` before you altered it. I suspect that update statements with joins weren't included in SQLite because they're powerful but a bit risky.

Using the pattern above you end up with two `country` fields. You can avoid that by explicitly stating all of the columns you want to retrieve from `destination_old` and perhaps using `coalesce` to retrieve the values from `destination_old` if the `country` field in `source` is null. So for example:

```
create table destination as select
d.field1, d.field2,...,coalesce(s.country,d.country) country
from destination_old d left join source s
on d.id=s.id;
```

Comment: What is `country` and where is it coming from? Don't try to be clever with snippets like these please. Just show the basics. Like you did with the first statement. If you must get clever, please provide a description.

Answer (score 5):

```
insert into firstTable (column1, column2, ...) select column1, column2,...  from secondTable;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

If you're copying data like that, that probably means your datamodel isn't fully normalized, right? Is it possible to make one list of countries and do a JOIN more?

Instead of a JOIN you could also use virtual tables so you don't have to change the queries in  your system.

Comment: We are updating from one table to another is a data clean up exercise only. I just need to update the country fields (spelling changes)

Comment: also because you can't modify columns

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a single record from one table to a second, with a new column in the destination table,

```
INSERT INTO destination (updatedate,colum1,column2,column3) SELECT DATETIME('now','localtime'),colum1,column2,column3 FROM source WHERE id=1
```

In the destination insert, specify the columns you want to update from the source table, then in the source table SELECT statement, specify the same columns you want copied and in the above case the destination table requires a timestamp of the copy operation, in the source table SELECT statement, the column representing the new column will include a DATETIME('now','localtime');

SQLite handles multiple statements, so you can append a DELETE query to the end of the COPY operation,

```
INSERT INTO destination (updatedate,colum1,column2,column3) SELECT DATETIME('now','localtime'),colum1,column2,column3 FROM source WHERE id=1; DELETE FROM source WHERE id=1;
```

Answer (score -1):

To copy column definitions from one table to another
You cannot copy individual columns from one table to another existing table by using Transact-SQL statements. However, you can create a new table in the default filegroup and inserts the resulting rows from the query into it by using SELECT INTO. For more information, see INTO Clause (Transact-SQL).
To copy data from one table to another
In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of Database Engine.

On the Standard bar, click New Query.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmployeeSales  
( BusinessEntityID   varchar(11) NOT NULL,  
  SalesYTD money NOT NULL  
);  
GO  
INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeSales  
    SELECT BusinessEntityID, SalesYTD   
    FROM Sales.SalesPerson;  
GO
```

Comment: What does TSQL have to do with this question? The tag is SQLite.