# Python - Bulk Select then Insert from one DB to another

Tags: python, sql, insert, bulk

I'm looking for some help on how to do this in Python using sqlite3

Basically I have a process which downloads a DB (temp) and then needs to insert it's records into a 2nd identical DB (the main db).. and at the same time ignore/bypass any possible duplicate key errors

I was thinking of two scenarios but am unsure how to best do this in Python

Option 1:

- create 2 connections and cursor objects, 1 to each DB
- select from DB 1 eg:

  ```
  dbcur.executemany('SELECT * from table1')
  rows = dbcur.fetchall()
  ```
- insert them into DB 2:

  ```
  dbcur.execute('INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (:column1, :column2)', rows)
  dbcon.commit()
  ```

This of course does not work as I'm not sure how to do it properly :)

Option 2 (which I would prefer, but not sure how to do):

- SELECT and INSERT in 1 statement

Also, I have 4 tables within the DB's each with varying columns, can I skip naming the columns on the INSERT statement?

As far as the duplicate keys go, I have read I can use 'ON DUPLICATE KEY' to handle
eg.

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (:column1, :column2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE set column1=column1
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Option 2 is impossible AFAIK, you should be able to go with option 1. Try doing option 1 and post the code if your having problems.

Comment: Well my testing code is basically as I wrote for option 1 - table and column names changed to make my post simple. 

I get an error attempting to do it like that - 'ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type'.  So I'm assuming I'm not passing in the values in proper format

Comment: Ah.. I should update to say my option 1 does work (I had something stupid in my code that conflicted with it).. the answer from unutbu is my preferred choice and works perfect!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) two databases to the same connection with code like this:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/temp.sqlite')
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('ATTACH "/path/to/main.sqlite" AS master')
```

There is no ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax in sqlite as there is in MySQL. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717590/sqlite-upsert-on-duplicate-key-update) contains alternatives.

So to do the bulk insert in one sql statement, you could use something like

```
cursor.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO master.table1 SELECT * FROM table1')
```

See [this page for information about REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) and other ON CONFLICT options.

Comment: Very nice, thanks!

I should note that testing this I could not use 'main' as the name for my attached DB, must be a reserved word - "OperationalError: database main is already in use"

Comment: I'm also giving INSERT OR IGNORE a try and see how it performs with my test data, I think this is my preferred route as data in the master db could have been modified slightly and I don't want to lose those changes.. thanks for the links, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The code for option 1 looks correct.

If you need filtering to bypass duplicate keys, do the insert into a temporary table and then use SQL commands to eliminate duplicates and merge them into the target table.