# Sqlite:How do I update a row or insert if it doesnot exsts in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite, upsert

I have a table with fields `menuid,name,price,quantity & spiciness`.

I want to `update Quantity` if the new  menuid and spiciness are same.Otherwise I need to add a new row if the new spiciness is different.

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite UPSERT - ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717590/sqlite-upsert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 1):

can use `insert or replace`. there must need a primary key in your table. if the key exist it will automatically update otherwise insert a new row

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table_name VALUES()
```

hopes it will help