# SQLite :if duplicate,increase counter

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite database with only 1 column that is filled with some names i get from a bunch of edittexts.I'm using it to power an autocomplete.
I've set the database to unique for that column so i won't get duplicates in my autocomplete.
The thing is that i'd like to make the following :
If someone enters a duplicate,make a counter for that name in the database.So if i enter "cheese" 5 times the "cheese" in the database will have 5 in a different column.
What i want to achieve with this is to show the autocomplete that is most often used first and to also have some kind of "top used names" listview or something.
Could you please help me with a snippet ? How can i detect when it tries to enter a duplicate into the DB and increment the counter ? 
Thanks ! Here's my code so far.

```
public class SQLiteCountryAssistant extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static final String DB_NAME = "usingsqlite.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION_NUMBER = 1;
private static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "countries";
private static final String DB_COLUMN_1_NAME = "country_name";

private static final String DB_CREATE_SCRIPT = "create table " + DB_TABLE_NAME +
                        " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, country_name text UNIQUE);)";

private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDBInstance = null;

public SQLiteCountryAssistant(Context context)
{
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION_NUMBER);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // TODO: Implement onUpgrade
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDBInstance)
{
    Log.i("onCreate", "Creating the database...");
    sqliteDBInstance.execSQL(DB_CREATE_SCRIPT);
}

public void openDB() throws SQLException
{
    Log.i("openDB", "Checking sqliteDBInstance...");
    if(this.sqliteDBInstance == null)
    {
        Log.i("openDB", "Creating sqliteDBInstance...");
        this.sqliteDBInstance = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }
}

public void closeDB()
{
    if(this.sqliteDBInstance != null)
    {
        if(this.sqliteDBInstance.isOpen())
            this.sqliteDBInstance.close();
    }
}

public long insertCountry(String countryName)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DB_COLUMN_1_NAME, countryName);

    return this.sqliteDBInstance.insert(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public boolean removeCountry(String countryName)
{
    int result = this.sqliteDBInstance.delete(DB_TABLE_NAME, "country_name='" + countryName + "'", null);

    if(result > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public long updateCountry(String oldCountryName, String newCountryName)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DB_COLUMN_1_NAME, newCountryName);
    return this.sqliteDBInstance.update(DB_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "country_name='" + oldCountryName + "'", null);
}

public String[] getAllCountries()
{
    Cursor cursor = this.sqliteDBInstance.query(DB_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {DB_COLUMN_1_NAME}, null, null, null, null, DB_COLUMN_1_NAME + " ASC");

    if(cursor.getCount() >0)
    {
        String[] str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;

        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
             str[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_1_NAME));
             i++;
         }
        return str;
    }
    else
    {
        return new String[] {};
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way to do, but one potential solution could be this:
Every time user enters a name, or perhaps every time the text in `EditText` changes (you could listen this with a `TextWatcher` listener), make a query to database in the following way (pseudocode):

```
SELECT ALL FROM countries WHERE country_name = editText.getText()
```

With other words, check if in `countries` table are already such text that the user is typing.   If the returned result is 0, you know this name never was queried, if the returned result is greater than 0, then you have to extract its associated count value in increment with one.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2718352/2529026

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO visits VALUES ($ip, 0);
UPDATE visits SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE ip LIKE $ip;
```

Replace `visits` with `countries` and `$ip` with `country`. This is the SQLite equivalent of

```
INSERT ..... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE ....;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,busy with my batchelor degree(Sociology,so you'll understand why i'm "such" a beginner with this,i have no programming background).From what i see,this doesn't resemble anything i've learned so far when it comes to android sqlite.Why is that ? Is this some other kind of sqlite ? How do i implement this in my project ? Sorry for this dumb question...i started learning like 3-4 weeks ago..

Comment: Do i have to do something like this ? String sql ="INSERT OR IGNORE INTO visits VALUES ($ip, 0)";db.execSQL(sql);  or db.execSQL(//command directly here); ? Sorry if i'm wrong,really hard to understand when starting from scratch and having to research every little detail,heh.

Comment: The example code is from a PHP question. $ip is a PHP variable. You'd replace that with your value. So, for example:

`INSERT OR IGNORE INTO countries VALUES('America', 0);` followed by `UPDATE countries SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE country = 'America'`

If there is no such country, it is added and its hit count set to 0 then immediately updated to 1. If there *is* such a country in the DB, the first statement is ignored and its hit counter is increased by 1.

You'd run this with something like `db.execSQL(sql);` where sql is your sql variable. I'm a bit rusty on my android sqlite interface.