# java.sql.SQLException: near "ON": syntax error

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Hey guys I have scoured the many other answers and am still unable to figure out this problem.

```
statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recentlyWatched (fileName STRING NOT NULL, fileLocation STRING, viewCount INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (fileName))");

Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:media.db");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO recentlyWatched (fileName, fileLocation, viewCount) VALUES ('"
                + fileName + "', '"
                + fileLocation + "', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE viewCount = '1'");
```

I have tried numerous ways to resolve this issue and am at a loss whenever i try to insert a record i get "java.sql.SQLException: near "ON": syntax error".

Update

Final code looked like this

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO recentlyWatched (fileName, fileLocation, viewCount) VALUES ('"
                + fileName + "', '"
                + fileLocation + "', 0)");
        statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE recentlyWatched SET viewCount = viewCount + 1 WHERE '" + fileName + "' LIKE fileName;");
```

Comment: I am using JDBC it works perfectly fine when i dont have ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE viewCount = '1'").

Comment: You should use PreparedStatement. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack.

Comment: I'll give it a shot with bind variables again and see how I go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As one can tell from `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")` you are using SQLite database which doesn't support the `ON DUPLICATE` clause. This is the reason why you get this error.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717590/sqlite-upsert-on-duplicate-key-update) question for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative I would suggest using it like this

```
("REPLACE INTO recentlyWatched (fileName, fileLocation, viewCount) VALUES ('"
                + fileName + "', '"
                + fileLocation + "', 0)
```

The difference is that is does a `DELETE` and then an `INSERT`