# Insert or Replace with sum of old values

Tags: sql, sqlite, cordova

I am building Inventory Application using PhoneGap.In that i have one module STOCK for stock management.

**Stock Table Query**

```
CREATE TABLE STOCK (
    sto_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    pro_id INTEGER FOREIGNKEY REFERENCES PRODUCT(pro_id) UNIQUE,
    quantity TEXT
)
```

**INSERT OR REPLACE Query**

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO STOCK (pro_id,quantity) VALUES ("1","5");
```

There is not a single issue with this query its working perfectly but i want to update SUM of OLD VALUES WITH NEW ONE.

Example:

```
pro_id quantity   
1       5
```

This is existing record so now when i will fire above query for new transaction which have 3 quantity then `quantity should be (5 (old) +  3 (new) ) = 8.`

So after updateing record it looks like.

```
pro_id quantity   
1       8
```

How can i solve this any idea. or let me know if i am on wrong way.
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you to INSERT new records which don't exist in the table first by checking them before inserting . Then UPDATE the existing ones by increasing / decreasing their amount via "quantity = quantity + '5'".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I am not real founder of this solution. The real hero is [Daverandom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889949/daverandom) with the help of him i have solve my issue.

He has suggest me to [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717590/sqlite-upsert-on-duplicate-key-update) solution and that is really helpful to find my solution.

Older query looks like as

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO STOCK (pro_id,quantity) VALUES ("1","5");
```

New Query looks like as

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO STOCK (pro_id,quantity) VALUES (1,0) ; 
UPDATE STOCK SET quantity = quantity + 2 WHERE pro_id=1;
```

**Update:**

If you will not add `WHERE pro_id="val"` in UPDATE then it will UPDATE all rows. 
So that will generate will appropriate result.

When user fire query first time then quantity will be 2 and when you fire same query second time it will 4.

So, We can change that value in each update.

Again thanks to Daverandom.

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite, you can create a trigger to handle such functionality:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1 BEFORE INSERT ON STOCK WHEN NEW.pro_id IN (SELECT pro_id FROM STOCK) BEGIN
    UPDATE STOCK SET quantity=COALESCE(NEW.quantity, 0)+COALESCE((SELECT quantity FROM STOCK WHERE pro_id=NEW.pro_id), 0) WHERE pro_id=NEW.pro_id;
    SELECT RAISE(IGNORE); -- Ignore INSERT
END;
```

From now on, whenever you try to insert an existing `pro_id`, update on `quantity` is done instead. Conflict clause (`OR REPLACE`) doesn't matter as trigger will handle it (for `pro_id`).

Yet another, this time without triggers, using single statement solution:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE STOCK(pro_id, quantity)
    SELECT npro_id, COALESCE(nqty, 0)+COALESCE(quantity,0) FROM (
        SELECT 123 AS npro_id, 9999 AS nqty
    ) LEFT JOIN STOCK ON npro_id=pro_id;
```

Just replace `123` with new `prod_id` and `9999` with new `quantity`.

Comment: Thanks but answer posted by me with the help of Daverandom is working perfectly :) +1