# On Duplicate Key not working in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, duplicates, primary-key

In my table, `id` is the primary key, but this code not working in sqlite3:

```
insert into text (id,text) VALUES(150574,'Hello') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'text' = 'good'
```

Please help me.

Comment: `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE` don't exist in SqLite. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717590/sqlite-upsert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: insert or replace ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE` don't exist in SqLite. But you can use `INSERT OR REPLACE` to achieve the effect like the following.

```
INSERT 
    OR REPLACE
INTO
    text (id, text)  
VALUES
    (150574,
        (SELECT
           CASE 
              WHEN exists(SELECT 1  FROM text WHERE id=150574)
              THEN 'good' 
              ELSE 'Hello' 
           END
         )
    )
```

Ref: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: a brief explanation of how to use INSERT OR REPLACE would benefit this answer. The link doesn't really mention much about the OR REPLACE part.

Answer (score 2):

Since SQLite version 3.24.0 (released 2018-06-04) there is `ON CONFLICT` support modeled after PostgreSQL. See [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) for more details.