# php query error sqlite near where syntax error

Tags: php, sqlite

hi i'm new in sqlite i'm trying to execute a query to sqlite database with php, but
**near where syntax  error ** occurs

here's the query:

```
"
  INSERT  INTO selectedObject ( museum , atwork , beaconCode , qrCode)
  VALUES ('".$museo."','" .$opera."','".$codiceBeacon."', '".$codice_qr_random."')
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                    SELECT museum , atwork
                    FROM selectedObject
                    WHERE museum = '".$museo."' AND atwork = '".$opera."'

                  )";
```

what's was wrong?

Comment: i try to modify the code without nested query and it works! how i can solve?

Comment: An `insert` does not have a `where` clause

Comment: it's possible to put a row if not already exists when i put that row into db?

Comment: @juergend - SQLite does support this syntax

Comment: But why have you tagged this question `MySQL` if you're using SQLite?

Comment: @Mark edited sorry...

Comment: @MarkBaker ok thank's....you suggest me to do another query to control it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite supports composite primary keys, so I show this from the Manual from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717590/sqlite-upsert-on-duplicate-key-update):

> A CREATE TABLE command specifies the following attributes of the new
>   table:

...

> Optionally, a PRIMARY KEY for the table. Both single
>   column and composite (multiple column) primary keys are supported.

Depending on your unique keys, primary or otherwise, composite or otherwise, you could use the sqlite functionality of `OR IGNORE` to ignore a `duplicate clash` followed by an update statement.

So it would become:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO selectedObject ( museum , atwork , beaconCode , qrCode)
  VALUES ('".$museo."','" .$opera."','".$codiceBeacon."', '".$codice_qr_random."');
```

And (possibly) followed by an `update` regardless.

Why do I say regardless? Because if the INSERT fails due to unique key clash, it fails silently. But that failure may be due to a single column unique index or a composite of two columns, but you want columns 3 and 4 set. So the update would mop it all up and make sure that row is there.

I will leave it to you to think about your use-case, and the update statement if needed.

`duplicate clash` meaning you have told the database to enforce uniqueness, whether that is a single column or a composite (combination of columns).