# Insert the newset value in a table and drop the old ones

Tags: sqlite, javadb

I have a method which saves somes records for a machine in a table. However, I may insert by accident multiple times the records for the same machine in a day, so I want for this day to save the newest insert and drop the old ones. I thought one solution:

```
String sq = "SELECT date, idMachine "
          + "FROM MACHINES_RECORDS WHERE date = ? AND idMachine = ?";

 try {       
        Class.forName(typeDB);
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(path);            
        stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);  
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {                
           do {
                 //call an another method to drop this value
               } while(rs.next());
         }else {
               //call an another method to insert this value
         }       
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (stm != null)
                stm.close();
            if (c != null)
        c.close();
  }
```

Is there any better/smartest solution from this, so I can make all theses actions in the same method?

Comment: MySQL or SQLite? They are different DMS and the solution can be different.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717590/sqlite-upsert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: @Pred: Thanks for spotting this. I hadn't even noticed the SQLite tag and answered for MySQL accordingly. I've updated my answer now to show how the same thing is done in SQLite.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thx for the update. It works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a unique index (possibly the primary key) on `date` and `idmachine` you would use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, so as to insert when there is no entry for that machine on that day or update the existing record with the new data otherwise.

```
insert into machines_records
  (machineid, date, data)
values
  (@id, @date, @data)
on duplicate key update data = @data;
```

**EDIT:** I see you removed the MySQL tag. So you want an answer for SQLite. In SQLite you'd use `INSERT OR REPLACE`:

```
insert or replace into machines_records
  (machineid, date, data)
values
  (@id, @date, @data);
```