# sqlalchemy: Bulk insert or update mappings

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want to create or update objects from a list of dicts using sqlalchemy.

Doing something like: `session.bulk_update_mappings(MyObject, list_of_dicts)`

And the problem is that I am getting integrity error, for cases when I there are some from the list_of_dicts are not in the database.

So I am kind of looking for a way to combine bulk_update_mappings and bulk_insert_mappings for one set of objects.

Comment: Which backend? MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is DB-specific. Take a look at this answer: [SQLite UPSERT - ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717590/sqlite-upsert-on-duplicate-key-update)

In MySQL we solve this problem by using

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

looks like you can achieve the same result in sqlite by using

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ... UPDATE ...
```

make sure you have a proper primary (or unique) key defined so the DB can identify the dups.