# Update table SQL

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a table that contains two columns CODE where there is all the bar code and VARIABLE initialized to 0 at the beginning . I have to update the table when I scan the bar code , I have to add 1 to variable , when I scan it twice VARIABLE =2.... 
I have tried to do it like but it does not work .Can anyone help?

```
 String query = "INSERT INTO TABLE (CODE,VARIABLE) VALUES(?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VARIABLE='"+VARIABLE+1+"'";

                try {
                    if (connect != null) {
                           PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                         statement.setString(1, "%" + res + "%");
                        statement.setInt(2,VARIABLE );

                        r=statement.executeQuery();
                        if (r.next()) {
                            message = "Updated";
                            String code = r.getString("CODE");
                            int var = r.getInt("VARIABLE");
                            INFOSOMME.setText(message);
                            INFOSOMME.setText(code);
                            INFOSOMME.setText(var);
                        } else {
                            message = "Error";
                            INFOSOMME.setText(message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        message = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                        INFOSOMME.setText(message);

                    }

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    etat = false;
                    message = "Got an exception!";
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }


            }
        });
```

ERROR: 08-03 09:43:44.966 30393-30393/com.example.practicas.myapplication W/System.err: Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'ON'.

I have tried to change the query to String query="INSERT INTO TABLE(CODE,VARIABLE) VALUES(?,0);" + "Update TABLE SET VARIABLE=VARIABLE+1 WHERE CODE LIKE ?"; and I got this error /System.err: The executeQuery method must return a result set.

Comment: post error log if you getting any error?

Comment: Have you tried VARIABLE+1 to put in ( ) so (VARIABLE+1)?

Comment: Give [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2718352/469080) a go, I think this is what you need. Basically `INSERT OR IGNORE` your barcode, then `UPDATE` the value in a subsequent statement.

Comment: why did not you use VARIABLE+1 as parameter as like VALUES(*?*,*?*) ?

Comment: Yes and I got the same error

Comment: I have tried to change the query to 

  String query="INSERT INTO TABLE(CODE,VARIABLE) VALUES(?,0);" +
                        "Update TABLE SET VARIABLE=VARIABLE+1 WHERE CODE LIKE ?";

and I got this error

/System.err: The executeQuery method must return a result set.

Comment: try with executeNonQuery() instead

Comment: Please for your own good, update the last value to be parameterized, else you're wide open to SQL Injection attacks.  Also as was suggested in one of the answers, you're not executing a query to return a result set, but rather a non query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the following SQL command:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TABLE (CODE,VARIABLE) VALUES(?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VARIABLE=(VARIABLE+1)";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still get the same error

Comment: try again with instead of "VARIABLE=(VARIABLE+1)" you enter "VARIABLE=(VALUES(VARIABLE)+1)"

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a comment but better here, I guess:

[executeNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Updates and Inserts don't return data, so you must not use executeQuery with them (which does return information apart from the amount of rows affected)

Comment: @Mimi did it work? If so, mark it as accepted answer, if not, let us know in order to help you further

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer . I changed the query String query = " Update TABLE SET VARIABLE=VARIABLE+1 WHERE CODE LIKE ?"; and it works. No more errors