# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ON": syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite

What is wrong with this SQL line? 
I've verified the types are correct.

```
c.execute('''INSERT into stock_table (item_name, stock, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stock=VALUES(stock);''', (str(entry["name"]), int(entry["amount"]), float(entry["price"])))
```

Comment: SQLite or MySQL? Depending on SQLite version, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2717590/1422451

Comment: SQLite. Good catch, it looks like this functionality isn't supported by sqlite.

Comment: @Parfait could you comment a solution for sqlite?

Comment: Please see aforementioned linked answer with SQLite solutions. Also, please re-tag post with one DBMS.

Comment: This error seems to occur on nix systems but not on windows.