# Insert multiple values SQLite android with the same query

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

Frequently in my app I need to insert a lot of values in a table of the DB.

So I'd need run an insert like:

```
insert into clients 
(id, name, lastip, visites) values  
('20','John','1.1.1.1','0'),
('21','Kate','1.1.1.2','3'), 
('35','Phill','1.1.1.3','90') ;
```

I have two questions about that (I'm starter with SQL)

1. How can I avoid crashes with primary keys (replacing the other columns if trying to inserting an existing row)?
2. Is there a way for inserting all the values in the same query using the method [`insert`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)() in [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) or a similar method? or I must build the query string and use [`execSQL()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29)?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1.) A possibility to avoid primary key crashes is to use auto increment fields.

> If a column has the type **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT** then a
>   slightly different ROWID selection algorithm is used. The ROWID chosen
>   for the new row is at least one larger than the largest ROWID that has
>   ever before existed in that same table.

See sqlite documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

If in your example `id` would be an auto increment field you do not need to specify it in the insert.

2.) Yes it is possible(for one row) like the documentation you refer to says:

```
public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
```

> values this map contains the initial column values for the row. The
>   keys should be the column names and the values the column values

However you should use prepared statements(reference here: [How do I use prepared statements in SQlite in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android))

If you want to insert all 3 rows with one shot you need to build the string or execute the inserts 3 times.

Edit to your comment:

3.) This is pretty well answered here: [INSERT IF NOT EXISTS ELSE UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634984/sqlite-insert-if-not-exists-else-update)

See also here: http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

> REPLACE
>
> When a UNIQUE constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE algorithm
>   deletes pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint violation
>   prior to inserting or updating the current row and the command
>   continues executing normally. If a NOT NULL constraint violation
>   occurs, the REPLACE conflict resolution replaces the NULL value with
>   he default value for that column, or if the column has no default
>   value, then the ABORT algorithm is used. If a CHECK constraint
>   violation occurs, the REPLACE conflict resolution algorithm always
>   works like ABORT.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really dont want to avoid the primary key crashes, what I need is update the row if already exists

Comment: @Adrmedi: I edited my post to incorporate additional information to your question

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `ContentProvider` to access your database, you can do this with `applyBatch()`:

```
// List of operations
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation) ops
    = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

// Create the builder
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder
    = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(...);

// Create the first item
builder.withValue("Name", "John");
builder.withValue("IP", '1.1.1.1');
ops.add(builder.build());

// Create the second item
builder.withValue("Name", "Kate");
builder.withValue("IP", '1.1.1.2');
ops.add(builder.build());

// Insert the data as one transaction
getContentProvider().applyBatch("AUTHORITY", ops);
```