# check if a row exists, if yes, update a column, else, insert a new row SQLITE JAVA ANDROID

Tags: java, android, sqlite, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [INSERT IF NOT EXISTS ELSE UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634984/insert-if-not-exists-else-update)

I want to check if a row (with it's ID) exists in a database, 
if yes, I want to update the column category, if it does not exist, i want to add a new row.
Is this possible via a single query in sqlite (will be applied inside eclipse using java for an android app)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's not possible. 
First you have to execute a query to check if a row exist, if yes, execute an update statement, if not, execute an insert statment...i think this are the way to go...

```
if(existsId(id)){
   updateCategory(categoryValue);
}else{
   addNewRow(newRowData);
}
```