# How to update or insert with SQLite.swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I want to update the column of a row if the row already exists, but if it doesn't exist yet then I want to insert a new row.

## Related questions

This type of question is popular for SQL in general

- [UPDATE if exists else INSERT in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208719/update-if-exists-else-insert-in-sql-server-2008)
- [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)
- [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

and SQLite in particular

- [INSERT IF NOT EXISTS ELSE UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634984/insert-if-not-exists-else-update)
- [SQLite - UPSERT *not* INSERT or REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace)
- [SQLite UPSERT / UPDATE OR INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277373/sqlite-upsert-update-or-insert)
- [SQL: How to update or insert if doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807472/sql-how-to-update-or-insert-if-doesnt-exist)

## Looking for SQLite.swift implementation

I'm trying to save development time by using the [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) wrapper for iOS development. I chose this framework because it was [recommended on raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift). I think it would be useful to have an example of the syntax for an update or insert.

## Strategy

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/418988/3681880), Sam Saffron says:

> If you are generally doing updates I would ..
>
> 1. Begin a transaction
> 2. Do the update
> 3. Check the rowcount
> 4. If it is 0 do the insert
> 5. Commit
>
> If you are generally doing inserts I would
>
> 1. Begin a transaction
> 2. Try an insert
> 3. Check for primary key violation error
> 4. if we got an error do the update
> 5. Commit
>
> This way you avoid the select and you are transactionally sound on
> Sqlite.

That makes sense to me, so in my answer below I am providing an example of the "generally doing updates".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this example, the user dictionary stores words that are typed on a custom keyboard. If the word is already in the dictionary, then that word's frequency count is incremented by 1. But if the word hasn't been entered before, then a new row is inserted with a default frequency of 1.

The table was created with the following schema:

```swift
let userDictionary = Table("user_dictionary")
let wordId = Expression<Int64>("id")
let word = Expression<String>("word")
let frequency = Expression<Int64>("frequency")        

// ...

let _ = try db.run( userDictionary.create(ifNotExists: true) {t in
    t.column(wordId, primaryKey: true)
    t.column(word, unique: true)
    t.column(frequency, defaultValue: 1)
    })
```

Taken from the question, this is what we want to do:

> 1. Begin a transaction
> 2. Do the update
> 3. Check the rowcount
> 4. If it is 0 do the insert
> 5. Commit

Here is how the code would look.

```swift
let wordToUpdate = "hello"

// ...

// 1. wrap everything in a transaction
try db.transaction {

    // scope the update statement (any row in the word column that equals "hello")
    let filteredTable = userDictionary.filter(word == wordToUpdate)

    // 2. try to update
    if try db.run(filteredTable.update(frequency += 1)) > 0 { // 3. check the rowcount

        print("updated word frequency")

    } else { // update returned 0 because there was no match

        // 4. insert the word
        let rowid = try db.run(userDictionary.insert(word <- wordToUpdate))
        print("inserted id: \(rowid)")
    }
} // 5. if successful, transaction is commited
```

See the [SQLite.swift documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md) for more help.