# Will this update my sqlite database correctly using android.sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have been struggling to get data from my sqlite database for the last 4 days because for some reason the queries I am using do not work. Here is my function:

```
public void updateBadgesRecord(int rowId, String id, String name, String description, String image_url, String club_id, String created_at) 
{

    Log.i("image_url in updateBadgesRecord", image_url);
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    if(id != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_ID, id);
    }
    if(name != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_NAME, name);
    }
    if(description != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_DESCRIPTION, description);
    }
    if(image_url != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_IMAGEURL, image_url);
    }
    if(club_id != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_CLUBID, club_id);
    }
    if(created_at != null){
    args.put(KEY_BADGES_CREATEDAT, created_at);
    }


    //return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE_BADGES, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    db.update(DATABASE_TABLE_BADGES, args, KEY_ROWID + "= ?",  new String[]{String.valueOf(rowId)});

}
```

Running this method appears to produce no errors.

But when I try and get all the data from this table:

```
public Cursor getBadgeRecord(int rowId) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_BADGES, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_BADGES_ID, KEY_BADGES_NAME, KEY_BADGES_DESCRIPTION, KEY_BADGES_IMAGEURL, KEY_BADGES_CLUBID, KEY_BADGES_CREATEDAT}, 
            KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    int columnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex("image_url");
    Log.i("mCursor", columnIndex+"<--- column index" + " | row id"+ rowId);
    return mCursor;
}
```

I get a Cursor record count of 0. What could be causing this? I have tried various different queries that should work so I am now at the point of giving up and not storing data with an sqlite database. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.update(...)` only *updates* existing rows. You probably want to do `db.insert(...)` [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

Comment: so I need to do a dbinsert to make the row exist before updating a row. updating will not automatically create a row if it doesnt exist already?

Comment: Exactly! (For deeper discussion see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634984/insert-if-not-exists-else-update)