# sqlite insert 1 row every day is same date

Tags: android, database, sqlite, date

I want to insert a row (`_id`,`rank`,`date`) in sqlite through android.
But i want the row to be only one per day.
So if i select another rank today it will overwrite the row, so that only the last row is kept every day

example i insert

```
(rank,date) -> (3,20140322)
(rank,date) -> (5,20140322)
(rank,date) - (2,20140322)
(rank,date) - (3,20140323)
(rank,date) - (6,20140323)
```

i want in the sqlite to be only

```
(rank,date) - (2,20140322)
(rank,date) - (6,20140323)
```

how can i define the date column? and how i can proceed to obtain to have only the last value every day?

Comment: Define a uniqueness constraint over the `date` column, and then use [`INSERT OR REPLACE`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3635038)?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `UNIQUE` constraint to your `date` column, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(...
   date TEXT UNIQUE, ...)
```

Then use `INSERT OR REPLACE` to do the inserts, e.g.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tablename(...,date) VALUES(..., 'todaysdate')
```

or using `ContentValues` with Android's convenience methods:

```
db.insertWithOnConflict(table, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

When the `UNIQUE` constraint (or any other constraint for that matter) is violated, the old violating rows are first removed and then the new row is inserted.