# SQLite Update and Increment with WHERE clause

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using SQLite and i am using a where clause to update a row in the database only if it exists and if it does not it needs to insert a new row

```
    public long createEntry(int x, int y, String date, int Version_Zero_HoursTable_One_DateTable)
{
    /*
     * first grab the values needed to increment the database values
     * */
    String[] column = new String[]{DATE,NUM_X,NUM_Y};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(HOURS_TABLE, column, date, null, null,
            null, null);    
    int current_x =0;
    int current_y  = 0;
    int iX = c.getColumnIndex(NUM_X);
    int iY = c.getColumnIndex(NUM_Y);
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        current_Y += c.getInt(iY);
        current_X += c.getInt(iX);
    }
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NUM_X, x + current_X);
    cv.put(NUM_Y, y + current_Y);
    cv.put(DATE, date);
    String WHEREargs = DATE+"="+date;
    if(Version_Zero_HoursTable_One_DateTable == 0)
    {
    return ourDatabase.update(HOURS_TABLE, cv, WHEREargs, null);
    //return ourDatabase.insert(HOURS_TABLE, null, cv);
    }
    else
    {
        return ourDatabase.update(HOURS_TABLE, cv, WHEREargs, null);
        //return ourDatabase.insert(DATE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you explain clearly, the problem is when you want to Update one row, two rows are Updated? Am I right

Comment: not exactly, i am editing my question now, the problem now is that i cant update a row that does not exist yet, so i am trying to figure out a way if that if can not update the row (because no row with that current date value exists), how can i insert a row and still return the values ? Thanks you for your help

Comment: What you mean the Last Word, Still returns the values

Comment: Yes, it does return the value, i am having problems coding whether to return an update or insert, how can you determine whether or not there are values that are being collected by the cursor?

Comment: Can you look my answer and END Of the answer there is a link

Comment: haha sorry, i cant upvote yet without a certain reputation level, but i did accept your answer that you posted, big help

Comment: Your welcome I am happy to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not compile it Because I am on phone. 
You can run 2 Script I think 
First you can run Update **there is no problem with this Because if the rows does not exists there is nothing **

Secondly you can ru Insert Script with where clause **the clause about the row not exists**

When I go to home i can Write Script if you do not Write,

Can you look this link
[INSERT IF NOT EXISTS ELSE UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634984/insert-if-not-exists-else-update)

Comment: The link you just sent was exactly what my code was missing, using insert or replace removes the need for the nested if loops (determining whether to update or insert) i just completed, i will refactor my code and update with answer when i can, Thankyou for your help