# Using FMDB to insert data and updating when there is a existing data?

Tags: ios, fmdb

I am using FMDB and I am inserting data into my database with:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into \"main\".\"DailyCycles\" ( \"objectID\",\"UserID\", \"Calories\") values ( '%@', '%@', %@)",
                 dailyTotal.objectId,
                 dailyTotal.userID,
                 dailyTotal.caloires,
                 ];
```

However, I don't want duplicates in the database. I've tried "update into" but then it won't insert new data. Is there a way to ensure that data is inserted into the database when there is no existing record while just updating any existing records?

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [INSERT IF NOT EXISTS ELSE UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634984/insert-if-not-exists-else-update)

By the way, be very careful when building your SQL queries like that. `NSString stringWithFormat` is not intended for such uses, and you might be opening the way to SQL injections. Here's how you should probably be doing it:

```
[db executeUpdate:@"insert into main.DailyCycles ( objectID, UserID, Calories) values (?, ?, ?)", dailyTotal.objectId, dailyTotal.userID, dailyTotal.calories];
```