# Storing duplicate records in SQLite database table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am storing data into SQLite table, and if data already exist(s) then updating it, and i am able to do that but whenever i update my existing record it saves another copy of that record...

**DatabaseDataHelper.java:-**

```
public class DatabaseDataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Data";
    // Table Name
    private static final String TABLE_MEMBER = "Data";

    public DatabaseDataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBER + 
                  "(Name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,"
                  " Title VARCHAR(50))");

        Log.d("CREATE TABLE","Create Table Successfully - classs");
    }

    public long InsertData(String strName, String strTitle) {

        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
            Val.put("Name", strName); 
            Val.put("Title", strTitle);

            long rows = db.insert(TABLE_MEMBER, null, Val);

            db.close();
            return rows;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public long UpdateData(String strName, String strTitle) {

        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
            Val.put("Title", strTitle);

            long rows = db.update(TABLE_MEMBER, Val, "Name=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(strName) });

            db.close();
            return rows;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }   
    }

    public String[] SelectData(String strName) {

        try {
            String arrData[] = null;    

             SQLiteDatabase db;
             db = this.getReadableDatabase();

             Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEMBER, new String[] { "*" }, 
                     "Name=?",
                     new String[] { String.valueOf(strName) }, null, null, null, null);

                if(cursor != null) {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        arrData = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];
                        arrData[0] = cursor.getString(0);
                        arrData[1] = cursor.getString(1);
                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return arrData;
         } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
         }
    }

    public boolean Exists(String strName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select 1 from Data where Name= ?", new String[] { strImageName });
        boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
        cursor.close();
        return exists;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBER);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
         String selectQuery = "Select * from "+ TABLE_MEMBER; 
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
         return cursor;
    }

}
```

**InsertDataActivity.java:-**

```
public boolean saveData() {
    long storeData = databaseDataHelper.InsertData(txtName.getText().toString(), editTitle.getText().toString());

    if (storeData <=  0) {
    } else
        storeData = databaseDataHelper.UpdateData(txtName.getText().toString(),
            editTitle.getText().toString());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: before you edit it, query in database that if same data is there or not.

Comment: can you show the query you are using to create the table ?

Comment: You are inserting the datum **anyway** (and storeData is **1**).

Comment: what's wrong here ? i have tried my best

Comment: Did you [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3635038/2591002) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - as SilentKiller said, **this method will increase database overhead as we're making one extra call**. The recommended method to solve this is by [using constraints in the SQLite database](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/constraints/), which is better IMHO.

---

in `InsertDataActivity` you are calling `InsertData()` without checking if the entry is already present. You should check whether the data is present or not, and then call `InsertData()` or `UpdateData()` accordingly.

Something like this should work.

```
  public boolean saveData() {
    String[] data = databaseDataHelper.SelectData(txtName.getText().toString());

    if (data != null) {
        storeData = databaseDataHelper.UpdateData(txtName.getText().toString(),
                editTitle.getText().toString());
    } else {
        storeData = databaseDataHelper.InsertData(txtName.getText().toString(),
                editTitle.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: by using your code it will increase one more action on database.

Comment: where you want me to do change in my sqlite ? and secondly why i am getting .journal file (and how can i control on making of it ?)

Comment: You can apply the UNIQUE constraint on the `ImageName` variable in the database. That will ensure that no two rows will have the same `ImageName`. No idea about the .journal thing, never encountered such a file.

Answer (score 2):

In your `InsertDataActivity` where you are inserting and updating data in database, you are inserting data first and then you are updating data. The approach is wrong.

> You should update first and check the affected row. if you get 0 row affected then only you need to insert that row.

**Try Following :**

```
public boolean saveData() {

    // This will Update record in the database if it is available and return row id of the updated database.
    long mNoRowsEffected = databaseDataHelper.UpdateData(txtName.getText().toString(), editTitle.getText().toString());

    // If we don't get any updated row id or if row id is null it mean the current record is not available in database 
    // so we need to insert this record to the database.
    if (mNoRowsEffected != null && mNoRowsEffected <= 0) {
        storeData = databaseDataHelper.InsertData(txtName.getText().toString(), editTitle.getText().toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks i have checked your answer as useful, but i am feeling comfortable by using Abhishek's answer